# python __init__ method in inherited class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, in-class-initialization

I would like to give a daughter class some extra attributes without having to explicitly call a new method. So is there a way of giving the inherited class an `__init__` type method which does not override the `__init__` method of the parent class?

I have written the code below purely to illustrate my question (hence the poor naming of attributes etc).

```
class initialclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 'one'
        self.attr2 = 'two'    

class inheritedclass(initialclass):
    def __new__(self):
        self.attr3 = 'three'

    def somemethod(self):
        print 'the method'


a = inheritedclass()

for each in a.__dict__:
    print each

#I would like the output to be:
attr1
attr2
attr3
```

Thank you

Comment: Call `initialclass.__init__` in the derived class constructor. However, the order of `attrX` is not guaranteed.

Comment: *Do not* override `__new__` unless you know exactly what it does and why you need to fiddle with it. You propably don't know. It's not another name for `__init__`. It's three levels more magic than one us usually concerned with, especially beginners.

Comment: Note that the argument to `__new__` is the _class_ of `self`, not `self`, as it's an implicit class method. So in your example you're actually setting the class attribute `inheritedclass.attr3`, not `self.attr3` as you thought.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible, however you can call the init method of the superclass, like this:

```
class inheritedclass(initialclass):
    def __init__(self):
        initialclass.__init__(self)
        self.attr3 = 'three'
```

Comment: brilliant, ive been trying to figure out a good way to handle this case for awhile

Comment: are there any downsides to this?

Answer (score 17):

Just call the parent's `__init__` using `super`:

```
class inheritedclass(initialclass):
    def __new__(self):
        self.attr3 = 'three'
        super(initialclass, self).__init__()
```

I strongly advise to follow Python's naming conventions and start a class with a Capital letter, e.g. `InheritedClass` and `InitialClass`. This helps quickly distinguish classes from methods and variables.

Comment: Specifically, use `super(DerivingClass, self).__init__()`. Or just `super().__init__()` in Python 3. Edit: -1 because 1. `super` needs the inheriting(!) class and 2. you override `__new__` needlessly, and the code as of now is in fact incorrect (it creates a **class** attribute `attr3`).

Comment: this works with the __new__ method but as lazyr told me (correctly) that I shouldn't use __new__, I think the correct answer for me yexo's. Thanks though!

Comment: @Anake Credit where credit is due, it was @delnan who told you not to use `__new__`, I just explained what your code actually did. By the way, `__new__` **must** return an instance of its class if you implement it. In the above answer, and in your code too, `inheritedclass() is None`! In other words, it doesn't work at all. (I mistakenly gave this answer an upvote, didn't read the code properly, and now I can't change it :(.)

Answer (score 6):

First of all you're mixing `__init__` and `__new__`, they are [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init). `__new__` doesn't take instance (`self`) as argument, it takes class (`cls`). 
As for the main part of your question, what you have to do is use `super` to invoke superclass' `__init__`.

Your code should look like this:

```
class initialclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 'one'
        self.attr2 = 'two'    

class inheritedclass(initialclass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr3 = 'three'
        super(inheritedclass, self).__init__()
```

Comment: thanks,my mistake about the new method. I am trying to use super and I keep getting this error: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj. (I copied and pasted you code exactly as well)

Comment: @Anake: `initialclass` needs to inherit `object` (`class initialclass(object)`), otherwise it's an old-style class, which is little more than a headache-inducing relic from the past and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

It's incredibly simple. Define a new `__init__` method and call the parent's `__init__` at the beginning.

```
# assuming a class Base, its __init__ takes one parameter x

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # whatever initialization is needed so we can say Derived is-a Base
        super(Derived, self).__init__(x)
        # now, add whatever makes Derived special - do your own initialization
        self.y = y
```

In Python 3, you don't have to (and therefore propably shouldn't, for simplicity) explicitly inherit from `object` or pass the class and `self` to `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a designated method from the parent's init, if it exists:

```
class initialclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 'one'
        self.attr2 = 'two'  
        if hasattr(self, 'init_subclass'):
            self.init_subclass()

class inheritedclass(initialclass):
    def init_subclass(self):
        self.attr3 = 'three'
```

Comment: Virtual -1. No need to do any extra work, let alone `hasattr` and extra methods, in the parent class. You can simply define a new `__init__` that calls the parent's `__init__` using `super`.

Comment: @delnan I know this, but the question was "is there a way of giving the inherited class an init type method _which does not override the init method of the parent class_". I've provided such a way. This has the added benefit of giving an entrypoint to calling _only_ the subclass init from some other subclass method.

Comment: That's why it's virtual. I know it's what OP asked for, but OP asked "How do I use a hammer to do this?" and the answer is "You use a screwdriver".

Comment: @delnan What I _thought_ OP asked was, to borrow your anology, "How do I use a hammer to do this when I don't want to use a screwdriver?". I assumed overriding included extending, since to my mind an extended method is simply a type of overridden method -- one that calls the parent method somehow. I assumed, wrongly it seems, he knew how to extend a method. By the way, aren't all python methods virtual? I've never heard anyone talk about virtual methods in python.

Comment: You're correct about Python methods being virtual, the -1 is virtual ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class initialclass:
        def __init__(self):
                self.attr1 = 'one'
                self.attr2 = 'two'
class inheritedclass(initialclass):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.attr3 = 'three'
        def somemethod(self):
                print (self.attr1, self.attr2, self.attr3)
a=inheritedclass()
a.somemethod()

 1. List item
```