# Why don't my subclass instances contain the attributes from the base class (causing an AttributeError when I try to use them)?

Tags: python, inheritance, class-attributes

I have this base class and subclass:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, sr1=None, foobar=None):
        self.sr1 = sr1
        self.foobar = foobar


# Event class wrappers to provide syntatic sugar
class TypeTwoEvent(Event):
    def __init__(self, level=None):
        self.sr1 = level
```

Later on, when I try to check the `foobar` attribute of a  `TypeTwoEvent` instance, I get an exception. For example, testing this at the REPL:

```
>>> event = TypeTwoEvent()
>>> event.foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TypeTwoEvent' object has no attribute 'foobar'
```

I thought that the base class attributes would be inherited by the subclass and that creating an instance of a subclass would instantiate the base class (and thus invoke its constructor). Therefore, I expected the `foobar` attribute value to be defaulted to `None`.

Why do `TypeTwoEvent` instances not have a `foobar` attribute, even though `Event` instances do?

Comment: As said below, you need to explicitly indicate that you want the superclasses to initialise as well. But __take care__: if you have any multiple inheritance then making this happen becomes very delicate.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The subclass should be:

```
class TypeTwoEvent(Event):    
    def __init__(self, level=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sr1 = level
```

Because `__init__` is overridden, the base class' `__init__` code will only run if it is explicitly requested.

Despite its strange name, `__init__` is not specially treated. It gets  called automatically after the object is created; but otherwise it's an ordinary method, and ordinary inheritance rules apply.

```
super().__init__(arguments, that, go, to, parents)
```

is the syntax to call the parent version of the method. Using `*args` and `**kwargs` allows us to [catch additional arguments passed to `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901) and [pass them to the parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847); this way, when a `TypeTwoEvent` is created, a value can be specified for the `foobar`, along with anything else specific to the base class.

Answer (score 4):

You're overriding the constructor (`__init__`) of the parent class. To extend it, you need to explicitly call the constructor of the parent with a [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) call.

```
class TypeTwoEvent(Event):
    def __init__(self, level=None, **kwargs):
        # the super call to set the attributes in the parent class
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # now, extend other attributes
        self.sr1 = level
        self.state = STATE_EVENT_TWO
```

Note that the `super` call is *not* always at the top of the `__init__` method in your sub-class. Its location depends on your situation and logic.

Comment: "Its location depends on your situation and logic." This is true, but it would be more helpful to explain the consequences of writing it later instead of at the top - what problems can be solved (or created) this way.

Answer (score 2):

When the instance is created, its `__init__` method is called. In this case, that is `TypeTwoEvent.__init__`. Superclass methods will not be called automatically because that would be immensely confusing.

You should call `Event.__init__(self, ...)` from `TypeTwoEvent.__init__` (or use `super`, but if you're not familiar with it, read up on it first so you know what you're doing).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `__init__` method of the base class from the `__init__` method of the inherited class.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636419/python-init-method-in-inherited-class) for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, but in my case I put `super().__init__()` on the bottom of my derived class and that's why it doesn't work. Because I tried to use attributes that are not initialized.

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: Hey @enesislam, yes, as far as I remember, it was something with trying to use attributes from parent class, but parent weren't initialized by calling parent constructor before.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. I solved my problem. I had `self.parent` in the parent class. When I try to use `super().__init__()` in child class it said the object has no attribute. So I have tried to use like `super().__init__(parent=self.parent)` but the result was the same. The true way to solve this problem is to send that parent value by args. So it should be: `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @enesislam Good catch! Glad you managed to get it solved!