# How to use super() to update a value in a specific instance of the parent?

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to use the super function to write a string into a list of a specific instance of a parent object. Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# test.py

class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Sub1(Master):
    list = []
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Sub2(Sub1):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Sub2, self).list.append(name)

m = Master()
m.foo = Sub1()
m.foo.bar = Sub2('something')

m.bla = Sub1()
m.bla.blub = Sub2('else')

print(m.foo.list)
```

In this case the output is of course

```
['something', 'else']
```

However I want it to be just `'something'`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
class Sub1(Master):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
```

Which yields:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Is there an easy solution?

Comment: I don't think you should be using inheritance here. Maybe pass a `parent` argument to `__init__`?

Comment: You have to call the `Sub1` constructor from your `Sub2` `__init__` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python class inheritance: AttributeError: '\[SubClass\]' object has no attribute 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268603/python-class-inheritance-attributeerror-subclass-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: Are you sure you really need inheritance here ? Inheritance is a `is-a` relationship, not a "contains" relationship.

Comment: No, i'm not really sure i need inheritance.... In this case it looks like `Master` contains `Sub1` which contains `Sub2`, but later i actually want to inherit certain parameters and methods. In the real life it's something like Animals --> Mammals --> Dogs.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, if you define `lst` as a class attribute in `Sub1`, it is shared among all instances, which is not what you want. So you have to define `lst` as an instance attribute in `Sub1` but then it has to be managed by an instance of `Sub1` and not an instance of `Sub2`. Here is a modified code that offers what you expect:

```
class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Sub1(Master):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lst = []
    def add(self, item):
        self.lst.append(item.name)

class Sub2(Sub1):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

m = Master()
m.foo = Sub1()
m.foo.add(Sub2('something'))

m.bla = Sub1()
m.bla.add(Sub2('else'))

print(m.foo.lst)
print(m.bla.lst)
```

Here is the ouput:

```
['something'] <-- m.foo.lst
['else'] <-- m.bla.lst
```

Rem1: When using `super()` the whole class hierarchy has to be collaborative (i.e. use `super()` in the constructor).

Rem2: In Python3, `super()` is equivalent to `super(classname, self)`

Rem3: Don't use `list` as a variable name (it is a builtin type)

Rem4: My code stores only the `name` attribute in the list to mimic the example your gave, but I guess that in real life you would rather store instances of `Sub2` in that list. To do so, simply remove the `.name` in the `add`function.

---

EDIT : Thinking a bit more about my answer, I came to another solution that may be closer to your initial attempt. Let me know which one works best for your actual problem...

```
class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Sub1(Master):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lst = []

class Sub2(Sub1):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        super().__init__()
        parent.lst.append(name)

m = Master()
m.foo = Sub1()
m.foo.bar = Sub2(m.foo, 'something')

m.bla = Sub1()
m.bla.blub = Sub2(m.bla, 'else')

print(m.foo.lst)
print(m.bla.lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your actual problem seems to be in the way you initialize `list`.

You need to assign it in `__init__()`, not within the class body, to avoid it being shared between all instances of the class (see [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)).

```
class Sub1(Master):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
```

Comment: The OP said they tried that and got an error. At this point you really can't call this an answer.