# Python implementation of Singleton

Tags: python, singleton, decorator

code goes first:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def get_instance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return get_instance

@singleton
class A:
    #...
```

Ok, the code above is an implementation of Singleton, I saw [this implementation in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init/674345#674345).

I don't understand why the singleton function returns a function but A is a class.
How does it worK?

Comment: @Jim, Sorry, I will be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A isn't a class in the end. The class A gets created, but then replaced with the function that singleton returns. So in the end, A ends up being a function.

But since you call a class to create a object, it ends up working pretty much the same way. But isinstance won't work.

P.S. you probably shouldn't use a singleton. In python it is almost always the wrong choice.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use a singleton? What if I implement the Singleton Design Pattern using __new__?

Comment: @Alcott search the site for Python Singleton, or read the questions in the "Related" list. It's been addressed many times.

Comment: @Alcott A singleton is just the same as a global variable. If you really need one just instantiate your singleton class once into a global variable instead of messing with this stupid caching hack, and replace everywhere `MySingletonClass()` with `MySingletonInstance`. Singletons are often a bad idea for the same reasons that globals are often a bad idea, and if your code *looks* like it's instantiating a new instance rather than referencing a global variable then it's **even harder** to figure out the secret communications channels between parts of your code that don't directly communicate.

Comment: @Alcott, if your singleton object has state, then you've created a global variable. If your singleton object does not have state then you've created a module. Either way using a singleton hasn't helped anything. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI for a demonstration of how to properly avoid global state.

Comment: @Winston, thanks for your link, but I'm not able to watch it, because I'm in China, :P

Answer (score 1):

When you call `MyClass()` after it's been decorated, you're right -- you're not actually calling a class, you're calling a function.

That function calls the class `if cls not in instances` and caches it, then returns the cached instance.

In other words, there is no reason `MyClass()` has to call the class directly -- it will work as expected as long as it returns an instance of the class.

Comment: Yep, it works fine. It saves a single instance and returns it whenever you call `MyClass()`.

Comment: True, but most of the time that doesn't matter -- you generally shouldn't need to check type in Python, you just use it, and it will give an error if it doesn't support the correct interface.

Comment: @agf, true. Although a few others things break like pickles. Its just enough that I'm slightly uneasy about replacing a class with a function.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I agree, there are better implementations (many in the Python Singleton" questions here) if you really need a singleton.