# Returning an instance of class from constructor

Tags: python, instance

I need to return an instance of Bike in the constructor. For example:

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.bikeColor = color
        return self #It should return an instance of the class; is this not right?

myBike = Bike("blue")
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'Bike'
```

If this is the case, how could I return an instance if its only suppose to `return None`?

Comment: No, it should return None as the error says

Comment: That's an initializer. If you want to return instances, try `__new__`

Answer (score 5):

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.bikeColor = color

myBike = Bike("blue")
```

Is enough. In Python, `__init__` is not really a constructor - it's an *initializer.* It takes an already constructed object and initializes it (for example, setting its `bikeColor` attribute.

Python also has something closer to a constructor semantically - the `__new__` method. You can read about it online ([here is a good SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)), but I suspect you don't really need it at this point.

Comment: `__init__` is just as much a constructor as any C++ or Java constructor, which also initialize the members of objects that already exist by the time they're called. I don't recall seeing `return this` in any C++ or Java constructors. The `__new__` method does something **you can't do** in Java or C++. I see it very often claimed that `__init__` should be called an initializer, while `__new__` is a constructor, and it really confuses me.

Comment: Sounds like you have a dispute with the terminology.  The important thing to note is that Eli's description of what happens is essentially correct on all counts.  If you want to call it something different, that's up to you.

Comment: @Raymond Yes, I have a dispute with the terminology. I don't want to call it something different, I want to keep using the same word for the concept that was in use for decades before Python was developed. "`__init__` is not really a constructor" is needlessly confusing for new Python programmers who are already familiar with constructors, especially when you follow it up with "`__new__` is a constructor", as `__new__` behaves even **less** like a Java/C++ constructor than `__init__` does.