# Error exception must derive from BaseException even when it does (Python 2.7)

Tags: python

What's wrong with the following code (under Python 2.7.1):

```
class TestFailed(BaseException):
    def __new__(self, m):
        self.message = m
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

try:
    raise TestFailed('Oops')
except TestFailed as x:
    print x
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise TestFailed('Oops')
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

But it looks to me that `TestFailed` does derive from `BaseException`.

Comment: For other people who can't figure out why they are getting this error: check to make sure you didn't accidentally do `def MyException(Exception): pass` rather than the required `class MyException(Exception): pass`. Easy mistake to miss.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[__new__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__) is a `staticmethod` that needs to return an instance.

Instead, use the [__init__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__init__) method:

```py
class TestFailed(Exception):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.message = m
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

try:
    raise TestFailed('Oops')
except TestFailed as x:
    print x
```

Answer (score 26):

Others have shown you how to fix your implementation, but I feel it important to point out that the behavior you are implementing is already the *standard behavior of exceptions in Python* so most of your code is completely unnecessary. Just derive from `Exception` (the appropriate base class for runtime exceptions) and put `pass` as the body.

```
class TestFailed(Exception):
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `__init__()` instead of `__new__()` to "initialize" classes. In most cases overriding `__new__` is not necessary. It is called before `__init__` during object creation.

See also [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

Answer (score 3):

The `__new__` implementation should return an instance of the class, but it's currently returning `None` (by default).

However, it looks like you should be using `__init__` here, rather than `__new__`.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
try:
    do something ...

except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError("Please select the right frame from dropdown !")
```