# Distributed system: Raise error thrown on server side on client side

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, distributed-system, raiserror

I have just started to create a distributed system that now got a single server and a bunch of clients. The language used is python and communication is done using sockets and JSON. When an error occurs on the server-side I send the error class-name and the error arguments to the client-side like this:

```
     except Exception as e:
         jsonResult = {"error":                                                                                 
                       {   
                           "name":e.__class__.__name__,                                                         
                           "args": e.args                                                                       
                       }                                                                                        
         }                                                                                                      

         jsonResult = json.dumps(jsonResult)                                                                    
         jsonResult += "\n"                                                                                     

         return jsonResult
```

And then try to raise it on the client-side like this:

```
          errorFunc = decodedReply["error"]["name"]
          args = decodedReply["error"]["args"]
          print (args)

          # Builds and appends the argumentstring to the error class-name.
          errorFunc += '('
          for arg in args:
              # Handles when the argument is a string.
              if isinstance(arg, str):
                  errorFunc += '\'' + arg + '\','
              else:
                  errorFunc += arg + ','

          # Removes the extra ',' from the string before adding the last ')'. 
          errorFunc = errorFunc[:-1] 
          errorFunc += ')'

          # Debugging print.
          print ("Here: " + errorFunc)

          raise exec(errorFunc)
```

When I do this I get the error

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

From what I read here: [Error exception must derive from BaseException even when it does (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957436/error-exception-must-derive-from-baseexception-even-when-it-does-python-2-7)

it looks like I have to declare it as a class. Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: Can you show the output of `print ("Here: " + errorFunc)` ?

Comment: `Here: ValueError('ABC')`
is the output. The error is one I have raised manually on the server-side.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Patience is a virtue :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to python you are raising something which is not an exception:

```
>>> type(exec("ValueError('ABC')"))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

You need to rewrite your code to have this:

```
>>> errorFunc = "ValueError('ABC')"
>>> exec('raise ' + errorFunc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: ABC
```