# how do I properly inherit from a superclass that has a __new__ method?

Tags: python, inheritance

Let's assume we have a class 'Parent' , that for some reason has `__new__` defined and a class 'Child' that inherits from it. 
(In my case I'm trying to inherit from a 3rd party class that I cannot modify)

```
class Parent:
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        # ... something important is done here with arg
```

My attempt was:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, myArg, argForSuperclass):
         Parent.__new__(argForSuperclass)
         self.field = myArg
```

But while

```
p = Parent("argForSuperclass")
```

works as expected

```
c = Child("myArg", "argForSuperclass")
```

fails, because 'Child' tries to call the `__new__` method it inherits from 'Parent' instead of its own `__init__` method.

What do I have to change in 'Child' to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Take a look at related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, it is not considered best practice to override `__new__` exactly to avoid these problems... But it is not your fault, I know. For such cases, the best practice on overriding `__new__` is to make it accept optional parameters...

```
class Parent(object):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'my value is', value
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

...so children can receive their own:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, for_parent, my_stuff):
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff
```

Then, it would work:

```
>>> c = Child(2, "Child name is Juju")
my value is 2
>>> c.my_stuff
'Child name is Juju'
```

However, the author of your parent class was not that sensible and gave you this problem:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        print 'my value is', value
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

In this case, just override `__new__` in the child, making it accept optional parameters, and call the parent's `__new__` there:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return Parent.__new__(cls, value)
    def __init__(self, for_parent, my_stuff):
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff
```

Comment: The Child is literally paying for the (coding) sins of the Parent.

Answer (score 8):

Child doesn't call Parent's `__new__` instead of its own `__init__`, it calls it's own `__new__` (inherited from Parent) *before* `__init__`.

You need to understand what these methods are for and when Python will call them. `__new__` is called to come up with an instance object, and then `__init__` is called to initialize the attributes of that instance. Python will pass the same arguments to both methods: the arguments passed to the class to begin the process.

So what you do when you're inheriting from a class with `__new__` is exactly what you do when inheriting any other method which has a different signature in the parent than you want it to have. You need to override `__new__` to receive Child's arguments and call `Parent.__new__` with the arguments it expects. Then you override `__init__` entirely separately (though with the same argument list, and the same need to call Parent's `__init__` with its own expected argument list).

There are two potential difficulties that could get in your way, however, because `__new__` is for customising the process of obtaining a new instance. There's no reason it has to actually create a **new** instance (it could find one that already exists), and indeed it doesn't even have to return an instance of the class. This can lead to the following issues:

1. If `__new__` returns an existing object (say, because Parent expects to be able to cache its instances), then you may find your `__init__` being called on already existing objects, which can be very bad if your objects are supposed to have changeable state. But then, if Parent expects to be able to do this sort of thing it will probably expect a bunch of constraints on how it is used, and sub-classing it in ways that arbitrarily break those constraints (e.g. adding mutable state to a class that expects to be immutable so it can cache and recycle its instances) is almost certainly not going to work even if you can get your objects initialised correctly. If this sort of thing is going on, and there isn't any documentation telling you what you should be doing to subclass Parent, then the third-party probably doesn't intend you to be subclassing Parent, and things are going to be difficult for you. Your best bet though would probably be to try moving all of your initialisation to `__new__` rather than `__init__`, ugly as that is.
2. Python *only* calls the `__init__` method if the class' `__new__` method actually returns an instance of the class. If Parent is using its `__new__` method as some sort of "factory function" to return objects of other classes, then subclassing in a straightforward fashion is very likely to fail, unless all you need to do is change how the "factory" works.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, when you call `Child("myarg", "otherarg")`, that actually means something like this:

```
c = Child.__new__(Child, "myarg", "otherarg")
if isinstance(c, Child):
    c.__init__("myarg", "otherarg")
```

You could:

1. Write an alternative constructor, like `Child.create_with_extra_arg("myarg", "otherarg")`, which instantiates `Child("otherarg")` before doing whatever else it needs to.
2. Override `Child.__new__`, something like this:

.

```
def __new__(cls, myarg, argforsuperclass):
    c = Parent.__new__(cls, argforsuperclass)
    c.field = myarg
    return c
```

I haven't tested that. Overriding `__new__` can quickly get confusing, so it's best to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

While brandizzi's answer works well for simple examples, I had to dig a little deeper in my own use case: How to properly inherit from a class that only uses `__new__` *and* the `Child` class has their own properties *and* you need to perform some operations/checks on the given data before actually creating the new object (so before `super().__new__`).

In my case this issue came up using the Shapely 2.0 package, trying to inherit from a `shapely.geometry.Polygon` class. There's an issue thread on the Shapely Github, and a working solution with custom `Child` attributes: https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1233#issuecomment-977837620

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point

class PropertyPoint(Point):
    _id_to_attrs = {}
    __slots__ = Point.__slots__  # slots must be the same for assigning __class__ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140968

    def __init__(self, coord: Tuple[float, float], name: str):
        self._id_to_attrs[id(self)] = dict(name=name)

    def __new__(cls, coord: Tuple[float, float], name: str):
        point = super().__new__(cls, coord)
        point.__class__ = cls
        return point

    ...  # Irrelevant code 
 
   @property
    def name(self):
        return self._id_to_attrs[id(self)]['name']

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._id_to_attrs[id(self)]['name'] = name

    ...  # Irrelevant code
```

For anyone who should come across the same issues, I hope you save some time with this solution.