# How can I memoize a class instantiation in Python?

Tags: python, caching, singleton, unique, memoization

Ok, here is the real world scenario: I'm writing an application, and I have a class that represents a certain type of files (in my case this is photographs but that detail is irrelevant to the problem). Each instance of the Photograph class should be unique to the photo's filename.

The problem is, when a user tells my application to load a file, I need to be able to identify when files are already loaded, and use the existing instance for that filename, rather than create duplicate instances on the same filename.

To me this seems like a good situation to use memoization, and there's a lot of examples of that out there, but in this case I'm not just memoizing an ordinary function, I need to be memoizing `__init__()`. This poses a problem, because by the time `__init__()` gets called it's already too late as there's a new instance created already.

In my research I found Python's `__new__()` method, and I was actually able to write a working trivial example, but it fell apart when I tried to use it on my real-world objects, and I'm not sure why (the only thing I can think of is that my real world objects were subclasses of other objects that I can't really control, and so there were some incompatibilities with this approach). This is what I had:

```
class Flub(object):
    instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, flubid):
        try:
            self = Flub.instances[flubid]
        except KeyError:
            self = Flub.instances[flubid] = super(Flub, cls).__new__(cls)
            print 'making a new one!'
            self.flubid = flubid
        print id(self)
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def destroy_all():
        for flub in Flub.instances.values():
            print 'killing', flub


a = Flub('foo')
b = Flub('foo')
c = Flub('bar')

print a
print b
print c
print a is b, b is c

Flub.destroy_all()
```

Which output this:

```
making a new one!
139958663753808
139958663753808
making a new one!
139958663753872
<__main__.Flub object at 0x7f4aaa6fb050>
<__main__.Flub object at 0x7f4aaa6fb050>
<__main__.Flub object at 0x7f4aaa6fb090>
True False
killing <__main__.Flub object at 0x7f4aaa6fb050>
killing <__main__.Flub object at 0x7f4aaa6fb090>
```

It's perfect! Only two instances were made for the two unique id's given, and Flub.instances clearly only has two listed.

But when I tried to take this approach with the objects I was using, I got all kinds of nonsensical errors about how `__init__()` took only 0 arguments, not 2. So I'd change some things around and then it would tell me that `__init__()` needed an argument. Totally bizarre.

After a while of fighting with it, I basically just gave up and moved all the `__new__()` black magic into a staticmethod called `get`, such that I could call `Photograph.get(filename)` and it would only call `Photograph(filename)` if filename wasn't already in `Photograph.instances`.

Does anybody know where I went wrong here? Is there some better way to do this?

Another way of thinking about it is that it's similar to a singleton, except it's not globally singleton, just singleton-per-filename.

[Here's my real-world code using the staticmethod get](https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/908a1842116dc26ca57e3e4db6802fa563bc2008/gg/photos.py#L74) if you want to see it all together.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove those things you said.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let us see two points about your question.

## Using memoize

You can use memoization, but you should decorate the *class*, not the `__init__` method. Suppose we have this memoizator:

```
def get_id_tuple(f, args, kwargs, mark=object()):
    """ 
    Some quick'n'dirty way to generate a unique key for an specific call.
    """
    l = [id(f)]
    for arg in args:
        l.append(id(arg))
    l.append(id(mark))
    for k, v in kwargs:
        l.append(k)
        l.append(id(v))
    return tuple(l)

_memoized = {}
def memoize(f):
    """ 
    Some basic memoizer
    """
    def memoized(*args, **kwargs):
        key = get_id_tuple(f, args, kwargs)
        if key not in _memoized:
            _memoized[key] = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _memoized[key]
    return memoized
```

Now you just need to decorate the class:

```
@memoize
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, somevalue):
        self.somevalue = somevalue
```

Let us see a test?

```
tests = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3), Test(2), Test(4)]
for test in tests:
    print test.somevalue, id(test)
```

The output is below. Note that the same parameters yield the same id of the returned object:

```
1 3072319660
2 3072319692
3 3072319724
2 3072319692
4 3072319756
```

Anyway, I would prefer to create a function to generate the objects and memoize it. Seems cleaner to me, but it may be some irrelevant pet peeve:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, somevalue):
        self.somevalue = somevalue

@memoize
def get_test_from_value(somevalue):
    return Test(somevalue)
```

## Using `__new__`:

Or, of course, you can override `__new__`. Some days ago I posted [an answer about the ins, outs and best practices of overriding `__new__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789315/287976) that can be helpful. Basically, it says to always pass `*args, **kwargs` to your `__new__` method.

I, for one, would prefer to memoize a function which creates the objects, or even write a specific function which would take care of never recreating a object to the same parameter. Of course, however, this is mostly a opinion of mine, not a rule.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that you could put the decorator directly on the class instead of on the methods. That was the key bit of info that I was missing. Your memoize decorator isn't *quite* what I need because strings aren't singletons like numbers are (and therefore `id`s aren't unique from one identical string to another), but for my simplified needs I was able to just use the first argument directly as the key.

Comment: @Robru surely my memoize is just some quick code I use in examples, do not pay much attention to it :)

Comment: Of course, after an hour of finessing your memoize decorator to work with my particular configuration of classes, it occurs to me that this solution is not actually going to work because I have a number of methods and functions that iterate over `ClassName.instances` dict in order to do operations on all loaded instances, and this particular memoization technique jumbles all the different instances of different classes into a single dict. It looks like I am going to have to go with `__new__` after all.

Comment: After a few more hours of fiddling, I gave up on `__new__` and went back to the decorator. I got it to work *exactly* as I wanted, including functional staticmethods! (decorators break staticmethods by default because the original class hides behind the decorator object). Solution here: https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/f367fcb6cab8043b1e9a4cdbc4a411b7291665e1/gg/common.py#L43

Comment: beware that when a input parameter is string or unicode, id('string') is not guaranteed to be unique. You should use it's hash instead.

Comment: @Robru Not all equal ints are guaranteed to have equal id's either. I don't recall the specifics, but if you check out `10**10` vs `100**5`, you'll find they're equal but don't share the same id. iirc there's some maximum number beyond which python stops retrieving the existing object for ints.

Comment: @brandizzi You're not being paranoid about not decorating classes. For one thing, unless I'm missing something, you can't extend the decorated class.

Comment: @Robru P.S. According to PyInt_FromLong https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong the only values that keep the property id(a)==id(b) if a==b are from -5 to 256. I've tested 257, and it does indeed have different ids if you instantiate it multiple times.

Comment: Another limitation of the decorate-the-class approach is that your "class" object is no longer actually the class, it's a wrapper function returned by your decorator. For normal use (calling it to instantiate an object) that's fine, but if you try to use it with e.g. `isinstance` or `issubclass` or any kind of introspection, it will have unexpected results.

Comment: When you say "Anyway, I would prefer to create a function to generate the objects and memoize it.", isn't that function get_test_from_value exactly a factory?  So we do like factories?

Answer (score 9):

The solution that I ended up using is this:

```
class memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
        self.__dict__.update(cls.__dict__)

        # This bit allows staticmethods to work as you would expect.
        for attr, val in cls.__dict__.items():
            if type(val) is staticmethod:
                self.__dict__[attr] = val.__func__

    def __call__(self, *args):
        key = '//'.join(map(str, args))
        if key not in self.cls.instances:
            self.cls.instances[key] = self.cls(*args)
        return self.cls.instances[key]
```

And then you decorate the *class* with this, not `__init__`. Although brandizzi provided me with that key piece of information, his example decorator didn't function as desired.

I found this concept quite subtle, but basically when you're using decorators in Python, you need to understand that the thing that gets decorated (whether it's a method or a class) is actually *replaced by* the decorator itself. So for example when I'd try to access `Photograph.instances` or `Camera.generate_id()` (a staticmethod), I couldn't actually access them because `Photograph` doesn't actually refer to the original Photograph class, it refers to the `memoized` *function* (from brandizzi's example).

To get around this, I had to create a decorator class that actually took all the attributes and static methods from the decorated class and exposed them as it's own. Almost like a subclass, except that the decorator class doesn't know ahead of time what classes it will be decorating, so it has to copy the attributes over after the fact.

The end result is that any instance of the `memoize` class becomes an almost transparent wrapper around the actual class that it has decorated, with the exception that attempting to instantiate it (but really calling it) will provide you with cached copies when they're available.

Comment: This was very helpful to me. I'll just add that my use case involved classmethods as well and therefore required adding these lines after the staticmethod check: `if type(val) is classmethod: self.__dict__[attr] = functools.partial(val.__func__, cls)`

Answer (score 2):

The parameters to `__new__` also get passed to `__init__`, so:

```
def __init__(self, flubid):
    ...
```

You need to accept the `flubid` argument there, even if you don't use it in `__init__`

Here is the relevant comment taken from [typeobject.c in Python2.7.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/typeobject.c#l2795)

```
/* You may wonder why object.__new__() only complains about arguments
   when object.__init__() is not overridden, and vice versa.

   Consider the use cases:

   1. When neither is overridden, we want to hear complaints about
      excess (i.e., any) arguments, since their presence could
      indicate there's a bug.

   2. When defining an Immutable type, we are likely to override only
      __new__(), since __init__() is called too late to initialize an
      Immutable object.  Since __new__() defines the signature for the
      type, it would be a pain to have to override __init__() just to
      stop it from complaining about excess arguments.

   3. When defining a Mutable type, we are likely to override only
      __init__().  So here the converse reasoning applies: we don't
      want to have to override __new__() just to stop it from
      complaining.

   4. When __init__() is overridden, and the subclass __init__() calls
      object.__init__(), the latter should complain about excess
      arguments; ditto for __new__().

   Use cases 2 and 3 make it unattractive to unconditionally check for
   excess arguments.  The best solution that addresses all four use
   cases is as follows: __init__() complains about excess arguments
   unless __new__() is overridden and __init__() is not overridden
   (IOW, if __init__() is overridden or __new__() is not overridden);
   symmetrically, __new__() complains about excess arguments unless
   __init__() is overridden and __new__() is not overridden
   (IOW, if __new__() is overridden or __init__() is not overridden).

   However, for backwards compatibility, this breaks too much code.
   Therefore, in 2.6, we'll *warn* about excess arguments when both
   methods are overridden; for all other cases we'll use the above
   rules.

*/
```

Comment: What you say makes sense, but how does my trivial example work without defining `__init__` at all? Shouldn't it also give me errors about incorrect number of arguments passed?

Comment: @Robru, I updated my answer with the explanation given in `typeobject.c`

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to figure this out as well and I put together a solution that combines some tips from other StackOverflow questions (links in the code comments).

If anyone still needs, try this out:

```python
import functools
from collections import OrderedDict

def memoize(f):

    class Memoized:
        def __init__(self, func):
            self._f = func
            self._cache = {}
            # Make the Memoized class masquerade as the object we are memoizing.
            # Preserve class attributes
            functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
            # Preserve static methods
            # From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174362
            for k, v in func.__dict__.items():
                self.__dict__[k] = v.__func__ if type(v) is staticmethod else v

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Generate key
            key = (args)
            if kwargs:
                key += (object())
                for k, v in kwargs.items():
                    key += (hash(k))
                    key += (hash(v))
            key = hash(key)
            if key in self._cache:
                return self._cache[key]
            else:
                self._cache[key] = self._f(*args, **kwargs)
                return self._cache[key]

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            """
            From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104047/how-can-i-decorate-an-instance-method-with-a-decorator-class
            """
            return functools.partial(self.__call__, instance)

        def __instancecheck__(self, other):
            """Make isinstance() work"""
            return isinstance(other, self._f)

    return Memoized(f)
```

Then you can use like so:

```python
@memoize
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Uploaded the full thing with documentation to: https://github.com/spoorn/nemoize