# Why do Python's @staticmethods interact so poorly with decorated classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, memoization

Recently, the StackOverflow community helped me develop a fairly concise `@memoize` decorator that is able to decorate not only functions but also methods and classes in a general way, ie, without having any foreknowledge of what type of thing it will be decorating.

One of the problems that I ran into is that if you decorated a class with `@memoize`, and then tried to decorate one of it's methods with `@staticmethod`, this would not work as expected, ie, you would not be able to call `ClassName.thestaticmethod()` at all. The original solution that I came up with looked like this:

```
def memoize(obj):
    """General-purpose cache for classes, methods, and functions."""
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        """Do cache lookups and populate the cache in the case of misses."""
        key = args[0] if len(args) is 1 else args
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]

    # Make the memoizer func masquerade as the object we are memoizing.
    # This makes class attributes and static methods behave as expected.
    for k, v in obj.__dict__.items():
        memoizer.__dict__[k] = v.__func__ if type(v) is staticmethod else v
    return memoizer
```

But then I learned about `functools.wraps`, which is intended to make the decorator function masquerade as the decorated function in a much cleaner and more complete way, and indeed I adopted it like this:

```
def memoize(obj):
    """General-purpose cache for class instantiations, methods, and functions."""
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        """Do cache lookups and populate the cache in the case of misses."""
        key = args[0] if len(args) is 1 else args
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return memoizer
```

Although this looks very nice, `functools.wraps` provides absolutely no support for either `staticmethod`s or `classmethod`s. Eg, if you tried something like this:

```
@memoize
class Flub:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        """It is an error to have more than one instance per foo."""
        self.foo = foo

    @staticmethod
    def do_for_all():
        """Have some effect on all instances of Flub."""
        for flub in Flub.cache.values():
            print flub.foo
Flub('alpha') is Flub('alpha')  #=> True
Flub('beta') is Flub('beta')    #=> True
Flub.do_for_all()               #=> 'alpha'
                                #   'beta'
```

This would work with the first implementation of `@memoize` I listed, but would raise `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable` with the second.

I really, really wanted to solve this just using `functools.wraps` without having to bring back that `__dict__` ugliness, so I actually reimplemented my own `staticmethod` in pure Python, which looked like this:

```
class staticmethod(object):
    """Make @staticmethods play nice with @memoize."""

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Provide the expected behavior inside memoized classes."""
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        """Re-implement the standard behavior for non-memoized classes."""
        return self.func
```

And this, as far as I can tell, works perfectly alongside the second `@memoize` implementation that I list above.

So, my question is: Why doesn't the standard builtin `staticmethod` behave properly on it's own, and/or why doesn't `functools.wraps` anticipate this situation and solve it for me?

Is this a bug in Python? Or in `functools.wraps`?

What are the caveats of overriding the builtin `staticmethod`? Like I say, it seems to be working fine now, but I'm afraid that there might be some hidden incompatibility between my implementation and the builtin implementation, which might blow up later on.

Thanks.

Edit to clarify: In my application, I have a function that does an expensive lookup, and gets called frequently, so I memoized it. That is quite straightforward. In addition to that, I have a number of classes that represent files, and having multiple instances representing the same file in the filesystem will generally result in inconsistent state, so it's important to enforce only one instance per filename. It's essentially trivial to adapt the `@memoize` decorator to this purpose and still retain it's functionality as a traditional memoizer.

Real world examples of the three different uses of `@memoize` are here:

- [On a function](https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/master/gg/gpsmath.py#L76)
- [On a method](https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/master/gg/widgets.py#L35)
- [On a class containing staticmethods](https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/master/gg/camera.py#L36)

Comment: Slight note `key = args[0] if len(args) is 1 else args` - `is` compares object identity and is implementation specific, and happens to work here as small integers are cached. This really should be `== 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several thoughts for you:

- The operation of a *staticmethod* is completely orthogonal to the operator of class decorators.  Making a function into a staticmethod only affect what happens during attribute lookup.  A class decorator is a compile-time transformation on a class.
- There isn't a "bug" in *functools.wraps*.  All it does is copy function attributes from one function to another.
- As currently written, your *memoize* tool does not account for the different call signatures for classmethods and staticmethods.  That is a weakness in *memoize* not in the class tools themselves.

I think you've imagined tools like class decorators, staticmethods, classmethods, and functools to have some sort of mutually integrating intelligence.  Instead, all of these tools are very simple and need the programmer to consciously design their interactions.

ISTM that the underlying problem is that the stated goal is somewhat underspecified: "decorator that is able to decorate not only functions but also methods and classes in a general way, ie, without having any foreknowledge of what type of thing it will be decorating."

It is not entirely clear what the semantics of *memoize* would be in each scenario.   And there is no way for Python's simple components to automatically compose themselves in a way that would be able guess what you really wanted to do.

My recommendation is that you start with a list of worked out example of memoize using with a variety of objects.  Then start building out your current solution to get those to work one at a time.  At each step, you will learn where your spec doesn't match what meoize actually does.

Another thought is that *functools.wraps* and *class decorators* aren't strictly necessary for this problem.  Both can be implemented manually.  Start with wiring your tool to do what you want it to do.  Once it is working, then look at replacing steps with wraps and decorators.  That beats trying to force the tools to your will in situations where they may not be a good fit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes my answer look a little sad - Good post Raymond. I think the OP's problem is expecting a class decorator to magically make methods behave in a certain way, while what's required is a bit more thought about design and decorating individual methods...(difficult to tell though)

Comment: I've expanded the Flub example, please review it. The reason that I asked if this was a bug in functools is that by default, a function doesn't have any attributes. So it seems to me like `wraps` would be most useful to somebody wrapping a class in a function, as I am. Am I the first person to ever decorate a class that also contains `@staticmethod` decorated methods? It seems to me like an obvious and not unreasonable situation that the authors of functools might have anticipated. Then again, why didn't Guido anticipate this by making `staticmethod` objects callable in the first place?

Comment: Basically, what it comes down to is that I don't understand exactly why it is that my `@memoize` class decorator is breaking `staticmethod`s and `classmethod`s, and I'm annoyed that I have to reimplement `staticmethod` from scratch in this seemingly obvious and common scenario.

Comment: Oh, and one last thing, sorry: It's clear to me what the semantics are of `@memoize` in each situation. If I decorate a class with it, that means that if I call the constructor with the same argument twice, I should get a cached instance the second time (eg, prevent duplicate instances), while if I decorate a function or a method with it, it should return cached results (in the case of methods, `self` becomes part of the cache key and thus different instances don't share cache by design). My application uses the same `@memoize` in all three situations with success.

Comment: (Having slept on it and just awoken with fresh eyes) I guess a better question would be "Why does decorating a class break the descriptor protocol, thus preventing `staticmethod` and `classmethod` objects from behaving as expected?"

Comment: @Robru The descriptor protocol is implemented in object.\_\_getattribute\_\_ and type.\_\_getattribute\_\_.  The *memoize* wrapper returns a function that hides them from dotted lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Decorating a class is used to potentially alter a class' construction. It's a kind of convenient but not quite the same as `__new__`.

```
# Make the memoizer func masquerade as the object we are memoizing.
# This makes class attributes and static methods behave as expected.
for k, v in obj.__dict__.items():
    memoizer.__dict__[k] = v.__func__ if type(v) is staticmethod else v
return memoizer
```

The above code is forcing your wrapper on methods inside your instance.

```
class Flub:
    @memoize
    @staticmethod
    def do_things():
        print 'Do some things.'
Flub.do_things()
```

I believe this should be the code you should be using - bear in mind that if you receive no args, then args[0] is going to `IndexError`

Comment: No, I've not explained myself very well at all. Your changes to Flub completely miss the point. `@memoize` specifically needs to decorate the class because I cannot allow more than one instance per argument passed to `Flub.__init__`. I don't feel it's unreasonable to want to have `staticmethods` just because the class is decorated in this way. I expanded the Flub example in the original question in the hopes of clarifying this.

Comment: Also, the `staticmethod` should behave as a static method, eg, it should be executed totally normally. It is not the thing that I am trying to memoize at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your decorator is accepting a class (that is, an instance of `type`) and returning a function.  This is (pretty much) the programming equivalent of a [category mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake); classes might look like functions in that they can be invoked (as a constructor), but that doesn't mean that a function that returns an instance is equivalent to the class of the type of that instance.  For example, there is no way that `instanceof` will give the right result, and moreover your decorated class can no longer be subclassed (because it isn't a class any more!)

What you should be doing is to adapt your decorator to detect when it is called on a class and in that case construct a wrapper class (either using `class` syntax, or through the `type` 3-argument constructor) that has the required behaviour.  Either that or memoize `__new__` (although be aware that `__init__` will be called on the return value of `__new__` if it is of the appropriate type, even if it is an already existing instance).

Comment: You are right that `instanceof` and subclassing are both broken with my memoizer as is. That doesn't bother me, because I like the simplicity of it (and I don't need either of those things). I am learning more about the descriptor protocol and it seems that Python just won't allow them to function in this way, necessitating my custom `staticmethod` reimplementation.

Comment: @Robru - right, except that the conclusion you should be drawing is that you need to work *with* Python's type system, not against it.  That means that a decorator that accepts a class should return another class, not a function.