# Passing a variable to a dialog

Tags: python, gtk, python-2.7, pygtk, canonical-quickly

I need to pass a message to an error dialog, to display it to the user.

### First attempt

*PreferencesDialog.py*

```
dlgError = ErrorDialog ('Have you been messing with the configuration files?')
dlgError.run ()
```

*ErrorDialog.py*

```
global message = None

def __new__(cls, msg):
    builder = get_builder('ErrorDialog')
    new_object = builder.get_object('error_dialog')
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)

    global message
    message = msg

    return new_object

def finish_initializing(self, builder):

    # Get a reference to the builder and set up the signals.
    self.builder = builder
    self.ui = builder.get_ui(self)

    global message
    self.builder.get_object ('lblMessage').set_text (message)
```

### Second attempt

*PreferencesDialog.py*

```
dlgError = ErrorDialog ()
dlgError.message = 'Have you been messing with the configuration files?'
dlgError.run ()
```

*ErrorDialog.py*

```
global message = None

def __new__(cls):
    builder = get_builder('ErrorDialog')
    new_object = builder.get_object('error_dialog')
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)

    return new_object

def finish_initializing(self, builder):

    # Get a reference to the builder and set up the signals.
    self.builder = builder
    self.ui = builder.get_ui(self)

    global message
    self.builder.get_object ('lblMessage').set_text (message)
```

Both throw the same exception;

```
self.builder.get_object ('lblMessage').set_text (message)
NameError: global name 'message' is not defined
```

Please assist. I'm using Quickly, GTK 3 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the `message` a member of the class instance, by setting it in `__init__`?

```
def __init__(self, msg):
  self._message = msg

def finish_initializing(self, builder):
  self.builder.get_object("lblMessage").set_text(self._message)
```

Comment: `TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: @RobinJ This is one of the reasons I find the Quickly stub code annoying... But that is easy to repair: replace `def __new__(cls, msg)` by `def __new__(cls, msg, *args, **kwargs)` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788976/how-do-i-properly-inherit-from-a-superclass-that-has-a-new-method/10789315#10789315). After that, you can use unwind solution, which I find is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a dialog where I passed my dialog a variable to put the text in an entry box.  Trick is to pass the variable into **new** and then when finish.initializing() is called put it in there.  Here's the code:

```
class QuerynameDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    __gtype_name__ = "QuerynameDialog"

    def __new__(cls, name):
        """Special static method that's automatically called by Python when 
        constructing a new instance of this class.

        Returns a fully instantiated QuerynameDialog object.
        """
        builder = get_builder('QuerynameDialog')
        new_object = builder.get_object('queryname_dialog')
        new_object.finish_initializing(builder,name)
        return new_object


    def finish_initializing(self, builder,name):
        """Called when we're finished initializing.

        finish_initalizing should be called after parsing the ui definition
        and creating a QuerynameDialog object with it in order to
        finish initializing the start of the new QuerynameDialog
        instance.
        """
        # Get a reference to the builder and set up the signals.
        self.builder = builder
        self.ui = builder.get_ui(self)
        self.builder.get_object('name_entry').set_text(name)
```