Python inheritance, not returning new class
I'm having problems understanding why the inheritance is not working in the following example:
import vlc

class CustomMediaPlayer(vlc.MediaPlayer):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def custom_method(self):
        print("EUREKA")

custom_mp = CustomMediaPlayer()
print(custom_mp)
custom_mp.custom_method()

This outputs:
<vlc.MediaPlayer object at 0x7743d37db8f0>

AttributeError: 'MediaPlayer' object has no attribute 'custom_method'

instead of a CustomMediaPlayer object, with the custom_method.
Why is this happening? Is it because vlc.MediaPlayer is a _Ctype class?

It's possible that the base class would implement __new__ in such a way that it returns objects based on internal logic, not the designated subclass.

@khelwood precisely so I believe: vlc.MediaPlayer#new. Definitely yucky behavior for python, I wouldn't expect that without thinking.

@khelwood Do you know of other third-party libraries doing something similar that has been asked about in the past? It seems to me that if this isn't a duplicate then it's perfectly answerable along the lines of your comment. (And if it is thus answerable, it might be better to generalize the idea like that for the sake of next time; and add cross-references to other related Q&A about __new__, and so on.)

_Ctype itself does very little. But MediaPlayer.__new__ (which you haven't overriden) is just returning a previously created instance of MediaPlayer, not creating a new instance of CustomMediaPlayer. (Or at least creating a new instance in a way that isn't aware of the subclass.)

Based on the above comments, do the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788976/how-do-i-properly-inherit-from-a-superclass-that-has-a-new-method help?

This can happen if the base class overrides the __new__ method, which controls what happens when someone attempts to instantiate the class. The typical behaviour is that a new instance of the given class argument is created; but the __new__ function is free to return an existing object, or create an object according to its own internal logic.
In their comment, Rogue links to the source code for the module, which does indeed override __new__. If there is a way to subclass vlc.MediaPlayer successfully, it should be listed in the module's documentation; otherwise the way to address this problem will depend on your specific requirements.
