# python closure local variables

Tags: python, singleton, closures

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674345/380231) a singleton decorator is demonstrated as such

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        print len(instances)
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance
```

but `instances` is 'local' to each class that is decorated, so I tried to be more efficient and use

```
def BAD_singleton(cls):
    instances = None
    def getinstance():
        if instances is None:
            instances = cls()
        return instances
    return getinstance

@BAD_singleton
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'test'
```

However, this gives an error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'instances' referenced before assignment
```

when `m = MyTest()` is called

I think I understand which this should not work (as the assignment to instances will be local and be lost between calls), but I do not understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: A more complete [`@singleton`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Singleton).

Comment: @ephemient Thanks.  That is a really useful looking page in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is python is cleverer than I am and identified that instances is made local by the assignment and does not go up-scope to find the assignment.  As pointed out in the comments by @GeeTransit this is possible in python3 via `nonlocal`

```
def nonlocal_singleton(cls):
    instances = None
    def getinstance():
        nonlocal instances
        if instances is None:
            instances = cls()
        return instances
    return getinstance

@nonlocal_singleton
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('test')
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I'd like to point out that by adding a `nonlocal instances`, you can fix the error. It's raised because the function doesn't see a "declaration" or any sort before the first use of the variable. In this case, `nonlocal instances` would be similar to `instances = some_value` but `some_value` is the same as the one outside.

Comment: @GeeTransit Edited accordingly!  Thanks!