# Python scope, dictionary and variables difference?

Tags: python, dictionary, scope

[Python scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146359/python-scope)
I have the same question but slightly different.

```
number = 0
def incrementNumber():
    number += 1
```

This one above does not work but this one below does why? Both are outside the function scope.

```
number = {'num':0}
def incrementNumber():
    number['num'] += 1
```

First one works if I add the variable as global

```
number = 0
def incrementNumber():
    global number
    number += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://christophe.vandeplas.com/2011/06/python-global-variables.html), it's similar to what you're doing. Specifically adam's comment.

> You don't assign to dictionaryVar, you assign to dictionaryVar['A'].
>   So it's never being assigned to, so it's implicitly global. If you
>   were to actually assign to dictionaryVar, you'd get the behavior you
>   were "expecting".

Comment: What does the "it's" refer to in the second sentence, the dictionaryVar or the dictionaryVar['A']? It seems like the dictionaryVar['A'], so is "adam" saying that dictionaryVar['A'] is implicitly global? Why is that the case. I would expect, like the blogger, that dictionaryVar['A'] wouldn't be implicitly global if dictionaryVar wasn't... Can you explain a little more in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `int` is not mutable, so when you do `number +=1` your are really updating where `number` points.  As you, in general, do not want changes to propagate up-scope with out 
explicitly telling it to, python does a copy-on-write and gives you a local variable number.  You than increment that variable and it is thrown away when the function returns

In the case of dictionaries, which are mutable, you are grabbing the up-scope reference and then mutating the underlying object, thus your addition propagates out of the function.

In the last case you have explicitly told python to *not* make number a local variable, thus the changes propagate out as you want.

related [python closure local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142993/python-closure-local-variables)