# Python Inheritance and __init__

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning Python and I've found something about how Python constructs a sub class which confuses me.

I have a class that inherits from the list class as follows.

```
class foo(list):
    def __init__(self, a_bar):
        list.__init__([])
        self.bar = a_bar
```

I know that `list.__init__([])` needs to be there but I'm confused about it.  It seems to me that this line will just create a new list object and then assign it to nothing, so I would suspect that it would just get garbage collected.  How does Python know that this list is part of my object?  I suspect that there is something happening behind the scenes and I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Where did you find this code? It's incorrect

Answer (score 3):

The multiple-inheritance-safe way of doing it is:

```
class foo(list):
    def __init__(self, a_bar):
        super(foo, self).__init__()
        ...
```

which, perhaps, makes it clearer that you're calling the baseclass ctor.

Comment: It needs a bit more than that to be MI-safe.

Comment: Such as all classes in the inheritance tree agreeing on `__init__` arguments using `super`. See [Python's super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 2):

You usually do this when subclassing and overriding the `__init__()` function:

```
list.__init__(self)
```

If you're using Python 3, you can make use of `super()`:

```
super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual object is not created with `__init__` but with `__new__`.  `__init__` is not for creating the object itself but for initializing it --- that is, adding attributes, etc.  By the time `__init__` is called, `__new__` has already been called, so in your example the list was already created before your code even runs.  `__init__` shouldn't return anything because it's supposed to initialize the object "in-place" (by mutating it), so it works by side-effects.  (See [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) and [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).)

Answer (score 1):

You're partly right:

```
list.__init__([])
```

"creates a new list object." But this code is wrong. The correct code _should_be:

```
list.__init__(self)
```

The reason you need it to be there is because you're inheriting from a `list` that has it's own `__init__()` method where it (presumably) does important to initialize itself. When you define your own `__init__()` method, you're effectively overriding the inherited method of the same name. In order to make sure that the parent class's `__init__()` code is executed as well, you need to call that parent class's `__init__()`.

There are several ways of doing this:

```
#explicitly calling the __init__() of a specific class
#"list"--in this case
list.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)     

#a little more flexible. If you change the parent class, this doesn't need to change
super(foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For more on `super()` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/1142167), for guidance on the pitfalls of super, see [this article](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).