# python : instantiation of object

Tags: python, initialization

```
class Team :
    def __init__(self):
        print "object instantiated"
```

To create an object of Team class,

```
>>> obj = Team()
object instantiated
```

From `obj` I can access member of Team class. But why is the following allowed?

```
>>> y = obj.__init__()
object instantiated
```

here some question it raises.

1. Why `obj` is able to call `__init__()` , is `__init__()` just like another method?
2. Whenever `__init__()` is called it will create an object (correct if i'm wrong here), so should `y` hold another instance of `Team`?

Comment: `init` initializes. It's not the same as a constructor in C++/Java see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init

Comment: `y` will be None, as `__init__()` does not return anything per spec.

Comment: [**Python __init__ and self what do they do?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)

Comment: [**A Guide to Python's Magic Methods**](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the "magic" (double underscore) methods are available as regular methods, in addition to their special uses. The `__init__` method does not actually create the object instance, it merely initializes the object after the `__new__` method has created it. (Note that `__init__` does not return anything, so `y` will be `None` after `y = obj.__init__()`.)