# Something with __new__ and property

Tags: python

I try to understand the following code from some OpenSource GitHub project. There is a class without `__init__` but with a `__new__` method. The code is given as:

```
class Node(object):
    #pylint: disable=W0404

    #Singleton-Pattern
    _instances = dict()

    def __new__(cls, name=None):
        """ Instanciates a node from a file, and (name=None) creates a new node 
            Caution: Filenames are always given relative to the root-dir
            When no name is given, a new node is created. """

        if(name!=None and cls._instances.has_key(name)):
            return(cls._instances[name])

        if(name==None):  # a new node, lets find a name
            for i in itertools.count(0):
                name = "node%.4d"%i
                if(cls._instances.has_key(name)): continue# new nodes might not been saved, yet
                if(path.exists("./nodes/"+name)): continue
                break


        self = object.__new__(cls)
        cls._instances[name] = self

        #actuall init-code
        from ZIBMolPy.pool import Pool #avoids circular imports
        self._pool = Pool() #Pool is a singleton
        self._name = name
        self._tmp = Store() #for thing that need to be stored temporarly
        self._obs = Store()
        self.parent = None

        if(path.exists(self.dir)):
            self.reload()

        #self.pool.append(self) #register with pool
        return(self)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @property
    def obs(self):
        return(self._obs)
```

I found one discussion beween the `__init__` method and the `__new__` method at [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)
According to the highest rated comment, one should only use new if one is subclassing an immutable type like `str`, `int`, `unicode` or `tuple`. But I think here it is used for some other reason. Further more I don't understand why the class `cls` should have a name (and why it should have anything todo with some folders) and why I can call

```
n= Node()
n.obs
```

like the function obs would be a property function, but it is actually not..

I am confused. If your not, I cant wait for your respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class uses `__new__` to implement a singleton pattern.

`__new__` produces the new instances for a class, but in this case it'll return an existing instance instead if the same name was used before. You cannot do this with `__init__`, because that is called *after* the instance has been created. Note that when `cls._instances.has_key(name)` is `False`, `self = object.__new__(cls)` is called to create a new instance of the class, which is then initialized and returned.

Why the class checks for existing paths in the `./nodes/` directory is not clear, that is an application-specific check that without further context cannot readily be exposed any further.

The `@property` decorator replaces a function with a [python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). When looking up an attribute from a class, Python will call it's `__get__` method if the attribute has one. The Python expression `n.obs` is translated into `type(n).obs.__get__(n, type(n))` by Python. A `property` object calls the wrapped function and returns the result when it's `__get__` is called.

Comment: Thank you for your respond.

So the only reason to use '__new__' is because sometimes I want to get a object which has been allready created right? This is only in the case 'if(name!=None and cls._instances.has_key(name))'. How should I possibly call the '__new__' function with name!=None? I mean evertime I create a Node-Object I call 'node=Node()' and then by default 'name=None'. Also I thought cls is a static global class for objects. So if I add a name to the global class cls than each object contains that name since each object is a subclass of cls - is that correct?

Comment: @Adam: See the [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) documentation; `cls` is a reference to the class object passed into the `__new__` method (like `self` is passed into methods referring to the current instance). `Node()` creates a new name for you if you don't pass one in (`name=None`), theoretically this project can pass in an explicit `name` when it needs to. In this case `cls` would refer to the `Node` class or any subclasses of `Node`.

Comment: @Adam: Python class objects usually (in Python 3, *always*), inherit from `object`, not `cls`. `cls` is just a local name for this method.

Comment: @Adam: `object` itself is immutable, so you cannot add anything to it.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I just recognised that what I asked was very basic and wrong - sorry for that.

But I somehow struggle with:`self = object.__new__(cls)`. Can I see somewhere what this method does? I guess it does the following: `return cls()` but then again __new__ of Node would call itself recoursivly?

Comment: @Adam: `object` is the *parent* class. If `Node.__new__` wasn't defined, the default implementation is `object.__new__`. Here `Node.__new__` *overrides* `object.__new__`, then calls it when needed.