# python assignment to an object inside itself

Tags: python, object, variable-assignment, self

I am working on a class in python and I don't know if I can assign to an object inside one of its methods. For example:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self = <something>
```

Is that assignment (line 3) is right?

Comment: The answer is "yes you can". But, why would you do that?

Comment: What would you expect that assignment to do?

Comment: You can assign to the name `self`, but that does not "assign to the object".  It won't have any effect on the object.

Comment: The only reasonable place to modify self (as opposed to initialize some self's args) is a constructor, in Python this is not `__init__` but `__new__` method. Probably, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/1265154 is worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is a reference to an object. If you assign to it, you change which object the variable self is referring to, but it does not modify anything outside that method.

The functionality is similar to the following code:

```
def change(a):
    a = 10
    print(a) # prints 10

x = 5
change(x)
print(x) # prints 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to the name `self`, but that does not "assign to the object".  It won't have any effect on the object.  It just assigns a value to a local variable called `self`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not "assign to the object".  Basically, your code will do two things:

1. Create a variable `self` that is local to `foo.__init__`:

   ```
   >>> class foo:
   ...     def __init__(self):
   ...         self = 'hi'
   ...         print(self)
   ...
   >>> foo()
   'hi'
   >>>
   ```
2. Afterwards, the `self` argument that was given to `foo.__init__` upon initialization of class `foo` will be overwritten.  In other words, after that line, you can no longer create instance attributes for `foo`:

   ```
   >>> class foo:
   ...     def __init__(self):
   ...         self = 'hi'
   ...         print(self)
   ...         self.attr = 'hello'
   ...
   >>> foo()
   hi
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attr'
   >>>
   ```

In summary, you *can* do what you described, but you really shouldn't.  It doesn't do anything positive for your code.  Instead, it will most likely cause problems later on.  And even if it doesn't, it will still confuse people reading your code.

---

Perhaps by "assign to the object", you meant that you want to make an instance attribute for `foo`?  If so, then the syntax would be like this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.<attribute name> = <something>
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> class foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.my_attribute = 'value'
...
>>> test = foo()
>>> test.my_attribute
'value'
>>>
```