# creating class object that normally looks like a float

Tags: python, magic-methods

I'm looking to roll my own simple object that can keep track of units for variables (maybe I'll be adding other attributes like tolerances too). Here is what I have so far:

```
class newVar():
    def __init__(self,value=0.0,units='unknown'):
        self.value=value
        self.units=units

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value) + '(' + self.units + ')'

    def __magicmethodIdontknow__(self): 
        return self.value


diameter=newVar(10.0,'m') #define diameter's value and units

print diameter #printing will print value followed by units

#intention is that I can still do ALL operations of the object
#and they will be performed on the self.value inside the object.

B=diameter*2
```

Because I don't have the right magic method i get the following output

```
10.0(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\pineCar\src\sandBox.py", line 25, in <module>
     B=diameter*2 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instance' and 'int'
```

I guess i could override every magic method to just return self.value but that sounds wrong. Maybe I need a decorator?

Also, I know I can just call diameter.value but that seems repetative

Comment: Do you want to have your units preserved (and updated) by operations on your values? For instance, should `newVar(10, "m") / newVar(5, "s")` give another `newVar` instance with units of `m / s`?

Comment: You might want to use [a library](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once tried to implement something similar myself, but never managed to finish it. One way is to implement a new class from scratch, which contains both the value and the units. But if you want to use it in calculations, you have to implement all the magic methods like `__add__` and `__mul__`. An alternative is to sub-class float itself:

```
class FloatWithUnit(float):
    def __new__(cls, val, unit):
        return float.__new__(cls, val)
    def __init__(self, val, unit):
        self.unit = unit
    def __str__(self):  
        return '%g %s' % (self, self.unit)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Subclassing float is apparently a bit tricky, so you have to implement `__new__` in addition to `__init__`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/674304/2647279) for more discussion. When entering such an object on the command line, it shows its units:

```
In [2]: g = FloatWithUnit(9.81, 'm/s^2')

In [3]: g
Out[3]: 9.81 m/s^2

In [4]: type(g)
Out[4]: __main__.FloatWithUnit
```

But when used in caluations, it behaves like a normal float

```
In [5]: g2 = 2 * g

In [6]: g2
Out[6]: 19.62

In [7]: type(g2)
Out[7]: float
```

Comment: Awesome! This looks like the exact answer to my question. I don't fully understand why the return from `__new__` cannot just be `return val`. Looks like I need to learn about subclassing

Comment: The issue of `__new__` vs `__init__` is a bit difficult. Basically, `__new__` gets called before `__init__` and **must** return some object. There are some good questions about its use here on SO, and you can find various tutorials around the net, see e.g. [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-new-method.html), [here](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.it/2008/01/pythons-new-and-init.html) and [here](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/__new__-python/). I must admit that I also don't understand all the details, I usually copy some example and modify it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can override many different operators, some of which are for emulating numeric types. You can find out more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

In the case of multiplication, all you need to do is override `__mul__(self, other)` like so:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    return self.value * other
```

You can also override other numeric operations like `__add__(self, other)` (for addition), `__sub__(self, other)` etc.

On a somewhat unrelated note, you might also want to think about what you want the behaviour be if one wanted to multiply to diameters together or add a weight to a diameter.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, you are probably better off overriding the the object's float representation as also mentioned by John, though it's not as clean as overriding the mathematical operators:

```
def __float__(self):
    return self.value
```

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that. I plan to use all of the operations available to a float with this object (the simple multiplication was just an example.) I don't think that overriding every magic method makes sense. I expected there to be a single magic method that would override all math operations, but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
class newVar():

    def __init__(self,value=0.0,units='unknown'):
        self.value=value
        self.units=units

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value) + '(' + self.units + ')'

    def __mul__(self, other):

        if hasattr(other, "value"):
            return self.value * other.value
        else:
            return self.value * other

diameter=newVar(10.0,'m')

print diameter 
print diameter*2
```

another possible solution would be to override the object float representation

```
class newVar():

    def __init__(self,value=0.0,units='unknown'):
        self.value=value
        self.units=units

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value) + '(' + self.units + ')'

    def __float__(self):

        return self.value

diameter=newVar(10.0,'m')

print diameter 
print float(diameter)*2
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about __ float __  but, I'm looking to be able to call just diameter with no modification or handling. If there is no other way I will just call diameter.value when doing math.