# Python Class TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

Tags: python, class

I have following class in file1.py

```
class api:
  def server(self):
    DEFAULT_SERVER = socket.gethostname()
    try:
      SATELLITE_SERVER = raw_input('Enter RedHat Satellite Server Name [%s]: ' % DEFAULT_SERVER)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print ""
      sys.exit(1)
    if not SATELLITE_SERVER:
      SATELLITE_SERVER = DEFAULT_SERVER
    try:
      SATELLITE_URL = 'http://' + SATELLITE_SERVER + '/rpc/api'
      CLIENT = xmlrpclib.Server(SATELLITE_URL, verbose=0)
      print "Welcome to RedHat Satellite Server %s" % CLIENT.api.systemVersion()
    except socket.error, e:
      print "Incorrect Server Name -", e
      sys.exit(1)
    return CLIENT

  def username(self):
    DEFAULT_LOGIN = getpass.getuser()
    try:
      SATELLITE_LOGIN = raw_input("Enter RedHat Satellite Login Name [%s]: " % DEFAULT_LOGIN)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print ""
      sys.exit(1)
    if not SATELLITE_LOGIN:
      SATELLITE_LOGIN = DEFAULT_LOGIN
    return SATELLITE_LOGIN

  def password(self):
    try:
      SATELLITE_PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("Enter Your Password: ")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print ""
      sys.exit(1)
    if not SATELLITE_PASSWORD:
      self.password()
    return SATELLITE_PASSWORD

  def __init__(self):
    CLIENT = self.server()
    SATELLITE_LOGIN = self.username()
    SATELLITE_PASSWORD = self.password()
    KEY = CLIENT.auth.login(SATELLITE_LOGIN, SATELLITE_PASSWORD)

  def __new__(self):
    return (self.KEY, self.CLIENT)
```

And I am calling this class in file2.py,

```
KEY, CLIENT = file1.api()
print KEY
print CLIENT
```

When I execute the file2.py then I get the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 24, in <module>
    KEY, CLIENT = satelliteapi.api()
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, may be something around retuning the values from the class, may be **new** is not the right way to return in this case. Please help.

Comment: What does `satlliteapi.api()` return?

Comment: what version of python is this?

Comment: where is `satelliteapi` coming from? Also what are `self.KEY` and `self.CLIENT`?

Comment: Class instantiation should always return an instance of the class (as you could imagine). If you just want the tuple, why don't you just use a function that creates both objects (CLIENT and KEY) and returns them instead of a class?

Comment: Sorry @Hoopdady and Padraic that was typo, I have corrected that. It is file1.api()

Comment: Hi @C.B.the python version is 2.7.5

Comment: This code is attempting to unpack (which involves interation) an instance of ``api`` to assign it to two names, ``KEY`` and ``CLIENT``. Since ``api`` doesn't define an ``__iter__`` method, it is not a sequence that can be iterated over, and this is illegal hence you get the error.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init about why you shouldn't be overriding ``__new__`` like you are.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, overriding `__new__` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) the way you should go about doing what you are doing. If you simply want to make it so you can easily unpack the `KEY` and `CLIENT` values, you can do the following:

```
class api(object):
....
def __iter__(self):
    return (value for value in (self.KEY, self.CLIENT))
```

`__iter__` is the special method that defines if a class may be iterated over. It returns an `iterator` instance (in this case, a `generator`) that can be used as a 'sequence' representation of an object. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/understanding-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols-what-exact) has a good explanation of the topic.

If you wanted to make it even more explicit, you can do:

```
class api(object):
....
def get_key_and_client(self):
    return self.KEY, self.CLIENT
def __iter__(self):
    return (value for value in self.get_key_and_client())
```

This lets you get the same information without needing to actually use the iterator, and makes the iterator an alias of the `get_key_and_client()` method.

Comment: Got an error `TypeError: __iter__ returned non-iterator of type 'tuple'`after chaning to `__iter__` so end up using the suggestion of @javidcf to use function instead of class.

Comment: @SGL Yeah, sorry, I forgot the `__iter__` command wouldn't propagate the unpack to to the returned ``tuple``. I edited the answer to correct, but definitely have a method as per javidcf's answer or my second example is the more clear option.