# Pool of hashable objects

Tags: python

I've made a highly recursive, hashable (assumed immutable) datastructure. Thus it would be nice to have only one instance of each object (if `objectA == objectB`, then there is no reason not to have `objectA is objectB`).

I have tried solving it by defining a custom `__new__()`. It creates the requested object, then checks if it is in a dictionary (stored as a class variable). The object is added to the dict if necessary and then returned. If it is already in the dict, the version in the dict is returned and the newly created instance passes out of scope.

This solution works, but

1. I have to have a dict where the `value` at each `key` is the same object. What I really need is to extract an object from a set when I "show" the set an equal object. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?
2. Is there a builtin/canonical solution to my problem in Python? Such as a class I can inherit from or something....

My current implementation is along these lines:

```
class NoDuplicates(object):
    pool = dict()
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        new_instance = object.__new__(cls)
        new_instance.__init__(*args)
        if new_instance in cls.pool:
            return cls.pool[new_instance]
        else:
            cls.pool[new_instance] = new_instance
            return new_instance
```

I am not a programmer by profession, so I suspect this corresponds to some well known technique or concept. The most similar concepts that come to mind are memoization and singleton.

One subtle problem with the above implementation is that `__init__` is always called on the return value from `__new__`. I made a metaclass to modify this behaviour. But that ended up causing a lot of trouble since `NoDuplicates` also inherits from `dict`.

Comment: "What I really need is to extract an object from a set when I "show" the set an equal object." I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Please provide code for your current implementation.

Comment: Indeed, memoization is a very similar concept.  Its scope is narrower but that might be appropriate for the majority of use cases.

Comment: You are right, @BrianCain, my implementation is very close to just memoizing the output of `__new__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would use a factory instead of overriding `__new__`. See [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/674304/3959454).

Second, you can use tuples of arguments needed to create an object as dictionary keys (if same arguments produce same objects, of course), so you won't need to create an actual (expensive to create) object instance.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Using a factory might also relieve me of using metaclasses to avoid calling `__init__` all the time.

Comment: By the way, Im new here. When I come up with a better implementation, how should I post it? As a seperate answer? as an edit to your answer? in the original question?

I don't want to screw up, steal "points" or offend anyone...

Comment: @Henrik Yes, with the factory you won't have to call special methods. Regarding self-answering you can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. (In short: no problem if you accept your own answer)