# Making a concrete class abstract, preserving the constructor

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Suppose you have a concrete class

```
class Knight(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sir {} of Camelot".format(self.name)
```

Now it happens that the class hierarchy has to change. `Knight` should become an abstract base class, with a bunch of concrete subclasses for knights of various castles. Easy enough:

```
class Knight(metaclass=ABCMeta):  # Python 3 syntax
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sir {} of {}".format(self.name, self.castle)
    @abstractmethod
    def sing():
        pass

class KnightOfTheRoundTable(Knight):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    @property
    def castle(self):
        return "Camelot"
    @staticmethod
    def sing():
        return ["We're knights of the round table",
                "We dance whenever we're able"]
```

But now all code that used `Knight("Galahad")` to construct a `Knight` is broken. We can instead keep `Knight` as it is and introduce a `BaseKnight`, but then code that checks for `isinstance(x, Knight)` and should work on any knight may have to be changed to check for `BaseKnight` instead.

How does one turn a concrete class into an abstract one, sparing both the constructor and the `isinstance` checks?

Answer (score 2):

Make the existing class a base class, but [overload `__new__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/674304/166749) to return a subclass when an attempt is made to instantiate the base class:

```
class Knight(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Knight:
            # attempt to construct base class, defer to default subclass
            return KnightOfTheRoundTable(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            obj = super(Knight, cls).__new__(cls)
            obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            return obj
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sir {} of {}".format(self.name, self.castle)
    @abstractmethod
    def sing():
        pass
```

Now `Knight("Galahad")` continues to work but returns a `KnightOfTheRoundTable`. `isinstance(Knight("Robin"), Knight)` return `True`, as does an `isinstance(x, Knight)` check on any other subclass instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution messing with `__new__` mostly works, but it has the downside where `Knight(...)` does not give you a `Knight`, and that `Knight` is just an ABC.

Writing `BaseKnight` is a bit cleaner, but then you have the problem

> code that checks for `isinstance(x, Knight)` and should work on any knight may have to be changed to check for BaseKnight instead.

which can be patched by adding

```
    def __subclasscheck__(object):
        return issubclass(object, BaseKnight)
```

to `Knight`. You  don't want this to affect the subclasses of `Knight`, though, so you do this *also horrible* hack:

```
    @classmethod
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, object):
        if cls is Knight:
            return issubclass(object, BaseKnight)
        else:
            return ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__(cls, object)
```

---

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BaseKnight(metaclass=ABCMeta):  # Python 3 syntax
    def __str__(self):
        return "Sir {} of {}".format(self.name, self.castle)

    @abstractmethod
    def sing():
        pass
```

That's the base, then you have the concrete `Knight` that redirects `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks:

```
class Knight(BaseKnight):
    def __init__(self, name, castle="Camelot"):
        self._name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def sing(self):
        return ["Can't read my,",
                "Can't read my",
                "No he can't read my poker face"]

    @classmethod
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, object):
        if cls is Knight:
            return issubclass(object, BaseKnight)
        else:
            return ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__(cls, object)
```

Finally, some tests:

```
class KnightOfTheRoundTable(Knight):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def castle(self):
        return "Camelot"

    def sing():
        return ["We're knights of the round table",
                "We dance whenever we're able"]

class DuckKnight(BaseKnight):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "Knight Quacker of Quack"

    def sing():
        return ["Quack!"]

isinstance(KnightOfTheRoundTable("John"), Knight)
#>>> True

isinstance(DuckKnight("Quacker"), Knight)
#>>> True
```

With the edit to to delegate back to `ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__(cls, object)` I no longer thing *either* solution is particularly nice.

It's worth noting, though, that

- You probably instantiate `Knight` way more than than you use `isinstance` against the concrete `Knight` type (prior to the ABC). It makes sense to keep crazy behaviour confined to small spaces.
- Changing `isinstance` means you don't have to change what `Knight` is, which means less damage to the codebase.

Comment: +1 for another valid solution, although I don't see why returning a subclass of `Knight` from `Knight.__new__` is so horrible. After all, a subclass instance *is* a `Knight`, right? Is there any place where this can go terribly wrong?

Comment: I've had to change a few things to fix a bug I overlooked. It's not really any nicer now, but I did give two benefits to the method.