# What is the design reason for the fact that if __new__ does not return an instance of cls, python does not invoke __init__?

Tags: python

There are many questions on SO asking why python doesn't always call `__init__` after object creation.
The answer, of course, is found in this excerpt from the documentation:

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.
>
> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

What is the design reason for this?

Comment: Why should `__init__` always be invoked?

Comment: I never said it should. I'm just wondering why it is how it is.

Comment: My guess would be that, if `__new__` doesn't return an instance of `cls`, Python doesn't have a value for `self` to pass to `__init__`.

Answer (score 3):

`__init__` does act like a constructor. It needs an instance to do its job like setting attributes and so on. If `__new__` doesn't return explicitly returns an instance, then `None` is returned by default.

Imagine that what will happen when `__init__` gets a `None` as an input and trying to set attributes? It will raise an exception called `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute xxxxx".`

So I think it's natural that not to invoke `__init__` when `__new__` returns None.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, you can't actually call a regular method with the first argument being anything other than an instance of the class (or a subclass):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

Foo.__init__()
# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Foo.__init__(3)
# TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

So `__init__` isn't called because it cannot *possibly* do anything other than immediately raise an exception.  Not trying to call it is strictly more useful (though I don't think I've ever seen code take advantage of this).

Python 3 has a slightly simpler method implementation, and this restriction is no longer in place, but the `__new__` semantics are the same.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to try to run a class's *initializer* on a foreign object, anyway.

---

For a more designy answer, rather than a "because it's this way" answer:

Overriding `__new__` is already a weird thing to do.  By default, it returns an uninitialized object, which is a concept that Python tries very hard to hide.  If you override it, you're probably doing something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, some_arg):
        if some_arg == 15:
            # 15 is a magic number for some reason!
            return Bar()
        else:
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, some_arg)
```

Let's imagine a Python variant that unconditionally called `__init__` on the return value.  I immediately see a number of problems.

When you return `Bar()`, should Python call `Bar.__init__` (which has already been called in this case) or `Foo.__init__` (which is for a completely different type and would break whatever guarantees `Bar` makes)?

The answer surely has to be that `Bar.__init__` is called.  Does that mean that you have to return an uninitialized `Bar` instance, using the mouthful  `return Bar.__new__(Bar)` instead?  Python very rarely requires you to call dunder methods outside of using `super`, so this would be highly unusual.

Where would `Bar.__init__`'s arguments come from?  Both `Foo.__new__` and `Foo.__init__` are passed the same arguments — those passed to `type.__call__`, which is what handles `Foo(...)`.  But if you explicitly call `Bar.__new__`, there's nowhere to remember the arguments you wanted to pass to `Bar.__init__`.  You can't store them on the new `Bar` object, because that's what `Bar.__init__` is supposed to do!  And if you just said it gets the same arguments that were passed to `Foo`, you severely limit what types can be returned from `__new__`.

Or, what if you wanted to return an object that already exists?  Python has no way to indicate that an object is "already" initialized — since uninitialized objects are a transient and mostly-internal thing only of interest to `__new__` — so you'd have no way to say not to call `__init__` again.

The current approach is a little clumsy, but I don't think there's any better alternative.  `__new__` is *supposed* to create storage space for the new object, and returning a different type of object altogether is just a really weird thing to do; this is the least-surprising and most-useful way Python can handle it.

If this limitation is getting in your way, remember that the entire `__new__` and `__init__` dance is just the behavior of `type.__call__`.  You're perfectly free to define your own `__call__` behavior on a metaclass, or just swap your class out for a factory function.

Comment: This is good but it sort of pushes the question away instead of answering it. *Why* doesn't python 2 allow passing a different type of object into a class's `__init__`?

Comment: fair!  but then, which `__init__` should be called — the one on the original type, or the one belonging to the type you returned from `__new__`?  and why?  if i were to hazard a guess, it's probably just that it's awkward and unusual to return an _uninitialized_ object of a different type from `__new__`, whereas returning an uninitialized object of the usual type is the default behavior.

Comment: also, keep in mind that the `__new__`/`__init__` dance is just the implementation of `type.__call__`, which you are free to completely change in a metaclass if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not THE design reason, but a nifty consequence if this design decision is that a class does not HAVE to return an instance of itself:

```
class FactoryClass():
    def __new__(klass, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            return OtherClass(*args, **kwargs)
        return super().__new__(klass)
```

This could be useful sometimes. Obviously if you're returning some other class object, you don't want the init method of the factory class to be called.

The real reason which I hope the above example illustrates, and the bottom line, is that any other design decision would be nonsensical. New is the constructor for Python class objects, not init. Init is no different from any other class method (other than it being auto magically called after the object has been constructed); whether or not any of them get called depends on what happens in the constructor. This is just a natural way to do things. Any other way would be broken.

Comment: That "obviously" phrase is begging the question :)

Comment: I suppose. Why would you want it called? It doesn't make sense. There is no instance of the factory class. In Python, new is the constructor, not init. Would you expect other class methods to be called? Of course not. They're not constructors, either. The call to init is dependent upon what happens when the constructor does its job. Any other situation just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: And when your design decision is driven by the alternative implementation being utterly nonsensical, it's probably one you can be confident in.

Comment: Indeed. This makes sense and is basically what everyone here is saying.

Comment: I haven't marked this, or any other answer as accepted because while everyone is saying that calling `__init__` on something other than an instance of the factory class would be broken, nobody has given a real life example of why I would want a class `Foo` with a `Foo.__new__` method that returns something other than a `Foo` *and* such that this other object is not sensibly initialized by `Foo.__init__`.

Comment: @DanielSank You can always initialize it "manually" before returning it. Anyway, there is a deeper reason. I'll add another answer.

Comment: @DanielSank Hopefully I'll get around to the answer I have in mind, but have you also considered that sometimes the factory class might want to return an object that has already been initialized, or to delay the initialization because it is expensive? Have a look at the [lazy initialization design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization#Python).

Answer (score 0):

If `__new__` doesn't return an instance of `cls`, then passing the return value to `cls.__init__` could lead to very bad things.

In particular, Python doesn't *require* you to return an instance of the same type of class.

Take this contrived example:

```
In [1]: class SillyInt(int):
   ...:     def __new__(cls):
   ...:         return "hello"
   ...:     

In [2]: si = SillyInt()

In [3]: si
Out[3]: 'hello'
```

So we've created a subclass of `int`, but our `__new__` method returned a `str` object.

It wouldn't make a great deal of sense to then pass that *string* to our inherited `int.__init__` method for instantiation.
Even if, in the particular case in question, it 'works' (in the sense of not throwing any errors), we may have created an object in an inconsistent state.

---

Ok, so what about a more concrete (albeit still contrived) example?

Say we create two classes which set the same attribute as part of their initialisation (in the `__init__` method):

```
In [1]: class Tree():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.desc = "Tree"
   ...:         

In [2]: class Branch():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.desc = "Branch"
   ...:
```

If we now create a subclass which, in a custom `__new__` method, wants to return a different type of object (which may sometimes make sense in practice, even if it doesn't here!):

```
In [3]: class SillyTree(Tree):
   ...:     def __new__(cls):
   ...:         return Branch()
   ...:
```

When instantiating this subclass, we can see that we've got an object of the expected type, and that the `Branch` initialiser was the one that was called:

```
In [4]: sillyTree = SillyTree()

In [5]: sillyTree.desc
Out[5]: 'Branch'
```

What would have happened if Python had unconditionally called the inherited initialiser?

Well, we can actually test this by calling the initialiser directly.

What we end up with is an instance of `Branch` which was initialised as a `Tree`, leaving the object in a very unexpected state:

```
In [6]: SillyTree.__init__(sillyTree)

In [7]: sillyTree.desc
Out[7]: 'Tree'

In [8]: isinstance(sillyTree, Branch)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: isinstance(sillyTree, Tree)
Out[9]: False
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it's also confusing because init is not the constructor. New is the constructor. Calling init the constructor just confuses things

Comment: Ok but this just pushes the question away such that we now want to ask why you would ever want a class `Foo` such that `Foo.__new__` makes something other than `Foo` instances *and* such that these other instances are not sensibly initialized by `Foo.__init__`. I suppose one can imagine reasons for that, but having one real example recorded in the answer would really help.