# Do you always have to use __init__ as constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Do you always have to use `__init__` as constructor?
2. How many constructors can you use it in one class?
3. Do you need to have 'self' as first argument or you can use any other name like 'shapes' instead of 'self'?

Comment: Please keep it to one question per post. I believe that there are duplicate questions for each of your individual queries.

Comment: `__init__` is actually an instance's initializer, it's optional, but can't be given a different name. In Python the constructor is called `__new__`. There's a default one, so again it's optional, however if you provide one it must use that name in order to override the default one. The first argument to the initializer can be named anything, but the instance being initialized will always be passed as the first argument whatever you choose to call it (so it's not optional).

Answer (score 1):

1. The constructor is optional. However, if you specify one, it must be named `__init__`; it cannot be named anything else (otherwise, how would Python know which function is the constructor?).
2. One, called `__init__` (though it can call out to other functions).
3. No, but using a name other than `self` will make your code harder to read by others, who expect the name `self` by convention.

Comment: 1: *No*, unless you want to have Python let you know a new instance has been created and want to do something with that instance when it just has been created. Like setting initial values for attributes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've clarified that point.

Answer (score 1):

The one and only constructor for initializing an instance is `__init__`.  If you want polymorphism, you simply have to be flexible about the way you parse and interpret `__init__`'s input arguments.  Do you *have* to use it?  No, you can omit it, in which case Python calls the `__init__` method of the superclass, if any.

There is also a method called `__new__`, called before `__init__`, but it is intended for a different purpose and behaves differently: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/3019689

And no, `self` can be renamed but the result will be less-readable, less-maintainable code since `self` is the well-established conventional name.