# __init__ argument mismatch between super and subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a class inherit from `datetime.date`, call the superclasses `__init__` function, and then add a few variables on top which involves using a fourth `__init__` argument on top of year, month and day.

Here is the code:

```
class sub_class(datetime.date):    
    def __init__(self, year, month, day, lst):  
        super().__init__(year, month, day)
            for x in lst:
                # do stuff

inst = sub_class(2014, 2, 4, [1,2,3,4])
```

This raises the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    inst = sub_class(2014, 2, 4, [1,2,3,4])
TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

If I remove the last argument I get the below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    inst = sub_class(2014, 2, 4)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lst'
```

I take it that this is due to a mismatch between `__new__` and `__init__`. But how do I solve it? Do I need to redefine `__new__`? In which case do I need to call the superclasses `__new__` constructor as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement `__new__`, and call it on the super-class; for example:

```
class sub_class(datetime.date):

    def __new__(cls, year, month, day, lst):
        inst = super(sub_class, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
        inst.lst = lst
        return inst
```

In use:

```
>>> s = sub_class(2013, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3])
>>> s
sub_class(2013, 2, 3)  # note that the repr isn't correct 
>>> s.lst
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never been 100% on the difference between `__init__ and `__new__`. I'm assuming I can not bother with an `__init__` function and do everything I would have done in init in `__new__ `?

Comment: That's correct, there's no need for an `__init__` in this case - just assign attributes to `inst` (not sure if there's a conventional name for that...) instead of `self`. For more information, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/674304/3001761