# super().__new__ call: Object takes no parameters

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit a datetime.date into a new object which takes an extra parameter:

```
class FullDate:
    def __new__(cls, lst, date):  # initiate the date class - bit complicated
        inst = super(FullDate, cls).__new__(cls, date.year, date.month, date.day)
        # do stuff
```

When I try to make an instance of the date I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 8, in <module>
    to_load = FullDate(y[key], key)
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/PyFi/lib/Statement/Classes.py", line 518, in __new__
    inst = super(FullDate, cls).__new__(cls, date.year, date.month, date.day)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I've been researching why this happens but have come up empty so far.

Comment: Given that you were [previously inheriting from `datetime.date`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28332396/3001761), why did you remove it?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's what surprised me the most! I reckon I inherited while I was updating the class, then pushed the wrong file to git. Feel dumb now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually derive `FullDate` from `datetime.date`.

try

```
import datetime
class FullDate(datetime.date):
...
```

However, I'm not quite sure this is going to work out like you hope it will; `datetime.date` actually comes from a C library, in most implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You are not extending `datetime.date`. Try:

```
class FullDate(date):
```

If you omit the base class (date), you are actually extending the `object` which has no parameters in its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First, make sure you are actually inheriting from date. Second, the more common pattern is to define a new `__init__` method on the child class. Something like:

```
def __init__(self, new_arg, *args, **kwargs):
    self.new_arg = new_arg
    super(child_class, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: I agree, but must refer you to this previous q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332396/init-argument-mismatch-between-super-and-subclass In this particular case __init__ doesn't work.