# Initializer vs Constructor

Tags: python, constructor, initializer

I have heard that the `__init__` function in python is not a Constructor, It's an Initializer and actually the `__new__` function is the Constructor and the difference is that the `__init__` function is called after the creation of the object and the `__new__` called before. Am I right? Can you explain the difference better and why do we need both `__new__` and `__init__`?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init

Comment: `__init__` *is* a direct equivalent to what other OO languages (especially Java and C++) tend to call a 'constructor'. AFAIK those languages don't really *have* any direct equivalent to `__new__`. But probably exactly because the 'constructor' equivalent doesn't really construct anything (and neither do C++ or Java 'constructors'), Python tends to refer to these both as the actual method names rather than calling *either* "the constructor".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In essence, `__new__` is responsible for creating the instance (thus, it may be accurate to say *that it is* the constructor, as you've noted) while `__init__` is indeed a way of initializing state in an instance. For example, consider this:

```
class A(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_method()

    def instance_method(self):
        print 'success!'

newA = A()
```

Notice that `__init__` receives the argument `self`, while `__new__` receives the class (`cls`). Since `self` is a reference to the instance, this should tell you quite evidently that the instance is already created by the time `__init__` gets called, since it gets passed the instance. It's also possible to call instance methods precisely because the instance has already been created.

As to your second question, there is rarely a need in my experience to use `__new__`. To be sure, there are situations where more advanced techniques might make use of `__new__`, but those are rare. One notorious example where people might be tempted to use `__new__` is in the creation of the Singleton class (whether that's a good technique or not, however, isn't the point).

For better or worse, you basically get to control the process of instantiation, and whatever that might mean in *your specific situation*.

Answer (score 3):

`__init__` is called with an already built up instance of the object as first parameter (normally called `self`, but that's just a parameter name).

`__new__` instead is called passing the **class** as first parameter and is expected to return an instance (that will be later passed to `__init__`).

This allows for example `__new__` to return an already-existent instance for value-based objects that are immutable and for which identity shouldn't play a role.

Comment: Which class do you refer to when you say that `__new__` is called passing the **class** as the first parameter?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: the class of the object being built. This can be the same class where you place `__new__` or a class derived from it (in case neither the derived nor other bases listed before this class defined a `__new__`)

Answer (score 1):

Considering [documentation on class customization](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) to more details.

According to that these methods are used in these way: `__new__()` to create object, and `__init__()` to customize it.

And as 6502 noticed, `__new__` is the special case of static method and gets class as its argument, while `__init__` gets object produced by `__new__`