# Appending to a class instance attribute in python

Tags: python, class, attributes, append

I have a list of class instances, and I want to append separate items to an attribute for each. However, I ended up appending each item to the attribute on *every* instance in the list. Example code below:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        example.xlist = []

classes = [example(), example(), example()]
i=0
for instnce in classes:
    instnce.xlist.append(i)
    i+=1
print("1st list:", classes[0].xlist)
print("2nd list:", classes[1].xlist)
print("3rd list:", classes[2].xlist)
```

I want the output to be:

```
1st list: [0]  
2nd list: [1]  
3rd list: [2]
```

but instead I get:

```
1st list: [0, 1, 2]  
2nd list: [0, 1, 2]  
3rd list: [0, 1, 2]
```

any ideas on what is happening / what I can change to get the desired output?

Comment: You should assign `self.xlist`, not `example.xlist`, in the `__init__()` method. `example.xlist` is shared by all instances.

Comment: Your `__init__()` method should contain: `self.xlist = []`. The code you have keeps assigning a new empty list to the one class attribute and so the call to `append()` operates on that one list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your constructor when you create the new list. Instead of creating `example.xlist`, you should try using `self.xlist` instead. In Python, the `self` keyword, refers to the specific instance and not the general object.

If we apply this change to your sample code, we get:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xlist = []

classes = [example(), example(), example()]
i=0
for instnce in classes:
    instnce.xlist.append(i)
    i+=1
print("1st list:", classes[0].xlist)
print("2nd list:", classes[1].xlist)
print("3rd list:", classes[2].xlist)
```

This code produces the correct output.

Comment: Note that `self` isn't a keyword, but only the conventional name we give to the first parameter of the methods, which will receive the instance as first argument. Also, `__init__` isn't really a constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791639/initializer-vs-constructor .

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo just in my example code, though your changes do solve that. My actual code gives the attribute a default value, like this:
```class example:
    def __init__(self,xl=[]):
        self.xlist = xl```
That seems to be causing my issues, perhaps because the same blank list gets assigned to each?

Comment: Got it! Could you please edit your question to fix the typo in your code so that someone can answer it fully instead of as a comment that might not be visible?

Comment: But to answer your question, you should use `self.xlist = xl.copy()` instead to create a new instance of a list that has the same value.