# Missing 1 required positional argument 'element'

Tags: python, python-3.x

`Type error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'element'`

I got the code from github. I wanted to run but it doesn't work. Can you help

```py
from equation import Equation

from time import sleep

def run_balance():

    """

    Runs the chemical equation balance algorithm

    """

    print('=================================================')

    print('Insert chemical equation with elements in\nparentheses followed by the number of atoms:')

    print('Example: (H)2 + (O)2 = (H)2(O)1')

    user_input = input('>>> ')
    
    try:

        equation = Equation(user_input)

        print('Balanced equation: ' + equation.balance())

        sleep(3)
    
        run_balance()
    
    except IndexError:

        print('Invalid input...')
    
        sleep(3)
    
        run_balance()
    
run_balance()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of \_\_init__() in the Equation class?

Comment: (1) Format the code properly. (2) Decide for one Python version and remove the wrong tag.

Comment: (3) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Where in github?  I don't see a module like this.

Comment: I second @MichaelButscher's first and third suggestions (I went ahead and did a first pass to fix the code formatting markup). I think the second suggestion is misapplied here - Python version differences are finite and I think ideally questions *ought to* include both Python 2 and Python 3 tags *unless* the question is only relevant to one of them or if the ideal answer cannot reasonably cover both.

Comment: *Almost* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self (but that question is likely to seem unrelated to asker's since it's focused on the implicit `self` argument, even though the principle is the same).

Comment: What our community ideally needs is a canonical `TypeError: ...() missing ... positional argument...` question and answer which *isn't* specific to `self` or any given function/method, which takes the bigger-picture view of "how do I approach understanding/debugging this error?"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an argument to `Equation`.

Check the documentation or source code of `Equation`. If you're running Python interactively, you can type `help(Equation)` and look for `__init__` to get you started.

Here's how you can infer this from the error message you got:

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'element'` means that

1. a function named `__init__`
2. was "called" (executed),  but
3. it was given one (1) less argument than it was supposed to get (and if you look at the function definition, the argument it was supposed to get is called `element`, in case that helps).

For example, maybe it was supposed to be called with two arguments but only got called with one, or supposed to be called with three and only got two, and so on. In proper Python code, the wrong number of arguments *always* causes a `TypeError` with that shape of message, and comes from Python itself checking the number of arguments.

4. [this detail doesn't matter in this case] "positional argument" means that in the definition of the function, it was not a keyword-only argument.

For the most part, this error tells you *exactly* what the problem is, but the error is bad in two ways:

- it doesn't tell you explicitly that it happened when constructing a class,
- it doesn't tell you what the class was.

We have to know that `__init__` is a special function name which is used by Python classes to *init*ialize themselves. This is normally called the "constructor", although [in Python the applicability of that name is a bit trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791639/initializer-vs-constructor).

Once you know that `__init__` is the "constructor"/initializer of a class, you can start looking around for where in your code a class is being constructed. This isn't always obvious but we have another clue to help:

By convention, only classes are named `LikeThis` - upper-case the first letter of each word, no separation between words. And the only thing with that name in your code is `Equation`. Odds are higher that the error is in *your* code rather than code other people have already tested and released, so it's *probably* the `Equation(user_input)` call which needs one more argument.

---

It's hard to get any more precise than that since you didn't share enough information - where did you get the `equation` module? where on GitHub (link!) did you get this code? did the error have any other information like line numbers or "traceback" (a bunch of lines that look like code)?

P.S. You wrote "Type error" instead of the actual standard name `TypeError`, which warns me that you might be re-writing the error manually but not paying enough attention to the precise details.