# NameError: name 'queue_id' is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, object, arguments

I want to be able to create an instance of a class, and call methods on this instance which will connect me to a service (SQS, if that matters). I then want to be able to call methods which will let me interact with that service.

For some reason, I keep getting this error on import:

```
    class AmazonQueue(queue_id):
NameError: name 'queue_id' is not defined
```

But as far as I can tell, this isn't even getting called at import, so I shouldn't get this error.

Inside AmazonQueue is this method:

```
def __new__(self, queue_id):
        conn = am_auth.BasicAuth()
        q = conn.create_queue(queue_id)
        return q
```

Which just returns an object representing authentication to the service, which I think SHOULD theoretically be available for other methods to run.

In my script I wanted this to run like this:

```
q = am_queue.AmazonQueue(queue_id='queue_id_goes_here')
```

and then have a method called inside AmazonQueue() like so:

```
q.post_message('blahblahblah')
```

So, why am I getting this error if I'm not even instantiating the class on import?

Comment: Class *definitions* are called at import, as defining a class is an executable statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your class definition the paramaters to `AmazonQueue` are the parent classes, not the parameters you would like to require for instantiation

One option could be to just create a function since your example use is pretty straightforward

```
def get_queue(queue_id):
  conn = am_auth.BasicAuth()
  q = conn.create_queue(queue_id)
  return q
```

One thing to consider is:

> In general, you shouldn't need to override **new** unless you're
>   subclassing an immutable type like str, int, unicode or tuple.

From [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) answer on stack overflow

Comment: So basically this is entirely due to my lack of familiarity with OOP in Python.