# Python : Wrapper class and constructor parameters

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like to create a simple wrapper class for `frozenset` that changes the constructor arguments. Here is what I have come up with (as I would do it in Java) :

```
class Edge(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        frozenset.__init__(self, {a, b})
```

I would like to have `Edge(0,1)` create`frozenset({0,1})`.

However, I get this error:

```
>>>Edge(0,1)
TypeError: Edge expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? Also, if all you want to do is change the way you construct the frozenset, why not define a two-argument ordinary function that returns a frozenset?

Comment: I want to be able to expand that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frozenset` is immutable, so you'll need to override the `__new__` method:

```
class Edge(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        return super(Edge, cls).__new__(cls, {a, b})
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Comment: ahh you beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the relationship between `__new__` and `__init__`. You need to override `__new__`. Check out [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)