# Why should I use "self" in a function?

Tags: python, methods

I have two questions regarding this piece of code:

```
class Enemy
    def __init__ (self, x):
         self.energy=x

jason=Enemy(5)
```

1. Why do I have to use `self` when I create functions and instance variables? What is the purpose of using it?
2. When we create the `jason` object, we assign it a life of `5`, as `Enemy(5)`. However, can class names take variables inside? Or is it the `__init__` function which makes it possible? (I'd expect something like, `class Enemy (x)`, when we declare the class).

Comment: `self` refers the current object.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html. Note that, as it's missing a colon, your code won't work anyway.

Comment: But if I didn't create jason, I wouldn't have an object. What would self refer to at that point?

Comment: @ArdaBoğa if you didn't create `jason` you wouldn't be calling `Enemy.__init__`, so it wouldn't matter! Declaring a method is just like declaring a function - you define the parameters now that will get passed to it later on.

Answer (score 0):

In python, for class methods, the first argument (which normally people name `self`) refers to the instance (object) of the class which was used to call the function, It does not have to be named self, but thats the convention.

Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(someotherself, i):
...             print(someotherself)
...             print(i)
...             someotherself.i = i
...
>>> CA(1)
<__main__.CA object at 0x00514A90>
1
<__main__.CA object at 0x00514A90>
```

When you do something like -

```
self.energy=x
```

You are setting the `energy` variable inside `self` (which denotes your current object) to x.

When you do -

```
jason=Enemy(5)
```

Python internally calls the `__init__()` method of Enemy with the values for x as 5 (and self as the current object). `__init__()` is called after object has been created by `__new__()` method, which is a class method, An SO question to help understand how `new` and `init` work - [Python's use of __new__ and __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

Comment: `__new__` is not a static method, it's a class method

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! I now understand that "self" refers to the object to be created in the program.