# Python read XY coords from text file

Tags: python, io

I have a text file with numbers stored in the following format:

```
93 407 77 400 94 365 109 372 
135 312 180 328
100 120 140 160
```

I want to place these values into two list. One for polygons and one for rectangles.

If a line has 8 numbers in it, then gets stored to the polygon list. If a line has 4 numbers in it, then it get stored in the rectangle list. Like so

```
polygon=[ [93, 407, 77, 400, 94, 365, 109, 372] ]

rectangle=[ [135, 312, 180, 328,], [100, 120, 140, 160] ]
```

I would then uses these values to draw either a rectangle or a polygon on a canvas.

Here is what my code is so far:

```
class getXYCoords:

    def __init__(self, textFile):

        self.textFile = textFile
        polygon = []
        rectangle = []

        with open(self.textFile) as f:

            for line in f:
                line = line.split() #strip EOL
                if line: #lines (ie skip them)

                    # Stores values into polygon list
                    if len(line) == 8:
                        line = [int(i) for i in line]
                        polygon.append(line)

                    # Stores values into rectangle list
                    elif len(line) == 4:
                        line = [int(i) for i in line]
                        rectangle.append(line)

        return polygon, rectangle

# Example program

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #polygon = []
    #rectangle = []

    # Get XY coordinates
    polygon, rectangle = getXYCoords('HAMH HUTC XY.txt')

    print(polygon,'\n')
    print(rectangle)
```

When I run the program I get this error message:

> line 46 in module
>      polygon, rectangle = getXYCoords('HAMH HUTC XY.txt')
>      TypeError: **init**() should return None, not 'tuple'

Comment: Error message is pretty clear... what don't you understand about this? Is there a reason you're using a class instead of a function?

Comment: I wanted to place this code in a separate python file, and thought I needed to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to represent your coordinate sets in a class, set the `polygon` and `rectangle` lists as instance members and refer to them through `self`.

Note that the `__init__` constructor shouldn't return anything and if you want to access your `polygon` and `rectangle` lists you need to create an object of `getXYCoords` (here called `coords`) and access its members with the "dot" syntax: `coords.rectangle`, etc:

```
class getXYCoords:

    def __init__(self, textFile):

        self.textFile = textFile
        self.polygon = []
        self.rectangle = []

        with open(self.textFile) as f:

            for line in f:
                line = line.split() #strip EOL
                if line: #lines (ie skip them)

                    # Stores values into polygon list
                    if len(line) == 8:
                        line = [int(i) for i in line]
                        self.polygon.append(line)

                    # Stores values into rectangle list
                    elif len(line) == 4:
                        line = [int(i) for i in line]
                        self.rectangle.append(line)


# Example program

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Get XY coordinates
    coords = getXYCoords('test.txt')

    print(coords.polygon,'\n')
    print(coords.rectangle)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `__init__()` doesn't return anything except for `None`. It wouldn't make sense for the constructor of a class to return anything else. In your code, it seems like you need Polygon and Rectangle as objects to be referenced later. If so, then you'd simply need to add `self.rectangle` and `self.polygon` as attributes to your class, and get rid of the `return` line:

```
def __init__(self, textFile):

    self.textFile = textFile
    self.polygon = []
    self.rectangle = []

    with open(self.textFile) as f:

        for line in f:
            line = line.split() #strip EOL
            if line: #lines (ie skip them)

                # Stores values into polygon list
                if len(line) == 8:
                    line = [int(i) for i in line]
                    self.polygon.append(line)

                # Stores values into rectangle list
                elif len(line) == 4:
                    line = [int(i) for i in line]
                    self.rectangle.append(line)
```

If you must return something when a class is called, you can use `__new__()` instead of `__init__()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help.