# Python: how to subclass a class with a classmethod

Tags: python, class, subclass

I am trying to make a subclass from a class with a @classmethod defined:

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,animal):
        self.animal = animal

    @classmethod
    def wild(cls,animal):
        return cls('wild '+animal)

class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self):
        Pet.wild('cat')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Cat().animal
```

This gives me the following error:

```
print Cat().animal
AttributeError: Cat instance has no attribute 'animal'
```

Probably I don't fully understand the concept of subclassing, I have been also trying to pass `self` to `Pet.wild` without much more success. Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT

I try to explain what I want to do: I would like to initialize parentclass (or superclass?) `Pet` from the `Cat` subclass using the classmethod `wild` and not using `__init__`. Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: you need to call Pet.__init__() in Cat.__init__() for self.animal to be defined

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are not calling [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to properly inherit from your base class. So, doing this:

```
Pet.wild('cat')
```

does not do what you expect.

---

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self,animal):
        self.animal = animal

    @classmethod
    def wild(cls,animal):
        return cls('wild '+animal)

class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cat, self).__init__('cat')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Cat().animal
```

Comment: furthermore, "Pet.wild('cat')" does nothing (this is a function, returning new object, and discarding it)

Comment: The `animal = 'pig'` in your answer does nothing.

Comment: It was a copy paste from OP. I can remove it.

Comment: Yes, this is the "standard" subclassing. But if I want to get 'wild cat' as initialization of animal this does not work. My idea was to try to initialize the Cat class without calling directly Pet.__init__() but just by using the other classmethod

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to add inheritance and extend Cat later here is how you would do it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) for the difference between `__new__` and `__init__`

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, animal):
        self.animal = animal

    @classmethod
    def wild(cls, animal):
        obj = cls.__new__(cls)
        obj.animal = "wind " + animal
        return obj 

class Cat(Pet):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print Pet.wild("cat").animal
    cat = Cat.wild("cat")
    house_cat = Cat("cat")
    print house_cat.animal, cat.animal
```

Here is what is going on under the covers. Cat inherits the `wild` classmethod too. So you don't have to call `Pet.wild` from within `Cat` constructor. You just call the `wild` classmethod directly on `Cat`. `cls` gets the `Cat` class and so the object created will be  `Cat` instance and not a `Pet` instance. However, at some point you will have to override some default behavior in constructor and that involves some amount of coding.

Comment: thanks, but say that more in general I don't want to re-pass `"cat"` all the time and add some specific attributes to the `Cat` which `Pet` does not have. By my understanding that's the idea of making subclasses, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: If you write an `__init__` method in your subclass, it will override the `Pet` __init__ method. The only way to get `animal` attribute is to call the Parent class' __init__ method. Also __init__ is different in a way that it doesn't return anything. So your return statement doesn't do anything within init

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't realize I was overwriting `__init__`. But then why don't I get an error when I call `Pet.wild('cat')`? If I understood correctly, this should than call the `Cat.__init__` (if I have overwritten `Pet.__init__`) which does not allow any input

Comment: The code snippet above does not call `__init__` explicitly. If you want that you should change the `__new__` to `__init__`. Which would call the default constructor and then you can just override the attributes you want to be different in a `wild` Pet

Comment: Also see my edit to the answer which shows how to use the classmethod from subclasses.