# why __init__ method in python strictly considered not as a constructor

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I am pretty new to Python. I just started to gather knowledge about OOP in python.

In OOP ,there is always the concept of constructor,but in python we see a different scenario. that is, it does not have a explicit constructor.

Though the `__init__()` method is considered a constructor in python, just not explicitly... It behaves in many ways like a constructor. e.g. it is the first lines of code which are executed. But strictly speaking, it would be wrong to call it a constructor. A new instance or the class in question, is already "constructed" by the time the method `__init__` is called. Could anyone provide a good explanation with example on this line I wrote: "*because a new instance is already "constructed" by the time the method `__init__` is called*"

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your explanation is correct.  Why do you want another?  (However, `__init__` is not "the first code which is executed".  `__new__` is executed first, and that is the constructor.)

Comment: How is this different from constructors in C++ and PHP? They all run after the new object is constructed by the system, then they initialize elements.

Comment: I think he's looking for something more in terms of implementation details.

Comment: It would probably be more accurate to call these "initializers", but "constructor" has become the traditional term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's use of \_\_new\_\_ and \_\_init\_\_?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)