# Call constructor of cls object in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to call the constructor of a `class` object in python. I managed to get it to work using the following few lines:

```
obj = cls.__new__(cls)
n = (List of attribute names)
v = (List of attribute values)

for s in n:
    setattr(obj, s, v[s])
```

I was wondering if there is a way to directly insert the attribute value +  name pairs into the constructor, cause the arguments are just ignored if i call the following:

```
obj = cls.__new__(cls, v)
```

p.s.: I am using `python3`

The class looks similar to this:

```
class InheritingClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, basic_attribute, another_attribute=None):
        super().__init__(basic_attribute=basic_attribute)
        self.another_attribute= another_attribute

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, basic_attribute=1):
       self.basic_attribute= basic_attribute
```

So nothing special there

Comment: What is the class you are trying to instantiate?

Comment: `cls(s, v)` calls your constructor. `__new__` creates the instance, `__init__` initialises it; both are called by `Foo(s, v)`. If you do `cls = Foo`, `cls(s, v)` does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Amadan thanks, that is what i was looking for

Comment: If you are aiming the object instances `obj` in your case it is better to use the `__init__` for that instead of `__new__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to directly insert the attribute value + name pairs into the constructor

Please don't do that. This would be the anti pattern. Instead, use the `__init__` method to set the values. The `__new__` method should be the memory space allocation that returns the object instance, `obj` in your case.

So you should probable better do this inside your `__init__`:

```
k = ['a', 'b', 'c']
v = [1, 2, 3]
d = dict(zip(k, v))

class C:
    def __init__(self, d):                
        for _ in d:            
            setattr(self, _, d[_])

ci=C(d)
print(ci.a) # 1
```

I used the dict as `__init__` parameter, where I used the `zip` method to create one.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is the constructor of Python class instead of `__new__`. Refer [Pythons use of new and init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To add, if you want to store arbitrary attributes to your class, you can use `dict.update` like so:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, basic_attribute=1, **kw):
        self.basic_attribute = basic_attribute
        self.__dict__.update(**kw)


class InheritingClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, basic_attribute, another_attribute=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(basic_attribute=basic_attribute, **kw)
        self.another_attribute = another_attribute
```

Then:

```
ic = InheritingClass('hi', a=1, b=20)
print(ic.a, ic.b)  # prints 1, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "How do you call the constructor on a class object?" you need to look at the comments from  Amadan way back on Aug 24, 2016 at 6:41.

The answer:

```
new_obj = cls()
```

Here's some example code that illustrates the point:

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        return cls()
    
c = C.c()
print(c) # displays <__main__.C object at 0x10ef16a90>

class D(C):
    pass
d = D.c()
print(d) # displays <__main__.D object at 0x10ef16370>
```

And so we see that you can instantiate an object from the cls object.

Now if we combine Amadan's comment with prosti's cool code for setting attributes, we get this:

```
class ObjectFactory:
    @classmethod
    def new(cls,**kwargs):
        return cls(**kwargs)

    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
      for _ in kwargs:
        setattr( self, _ , kwargs[ _ ] )

class Person(ObjectFactory):

    pass

person = Person.new( first = "John", last = "Doe" )

print(person)            # <__main__.Person object at 0x10fe49ff0>
print(person.__dict__)   # {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe'}
```