# How to create an object in python without using __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, object

So for this piece of code

```
class CircleT:

    def __init__(self,x,y,r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
```

Lets say I want to create a CircleT object named Circle1.

I would just have to do

Circle1 = CircleT(2,4,6)

But if I had this instead

```
class CircleT:

    def CircleT(self,x,y,r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
```

How would I go about creating the Circle1 object?

Comment: as written... `Circle1 = CircleT().CircleT(2, 4, 6)`

Comment: That makes `instance` equal to `None` since `CircleT` doesn't return anything.

Comment: How you'd instantiate the object in the second case is irrelevant, because you'd never write it that way.

Comment: Also, the object *is* created, just not initialized.

Comment: my bad... call `Circle1 = CircleT(); Circle1.CircleT(2, 4, 6)`

Comment: This question *almost* (but probably inadvertently) hints at the rationale for class methods: to provide alternate constructors for a class.

Comment: Just explicitly `return self` in `CircleT` with the first suggestion from @Aaron

Comment: @chepner [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/3220135) there already are class constructors... also [classmethods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Comment: @cdarke Yeah thats it, thanks for all the help!