# Python 3.x: How to save and load data from within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like a class that in its initialize checks if `filename` exists. If it does it should initialize itself with `filename`, otherwise it should run init. At a later point I can then run a `save` method, saving the entire object.

A sketch of what I want:

```
class data(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        if does_not_exist(filename): # create new
             [... expensive computations]
             self.save(filename)
        else: # load existing
            with open(filename,'rb') as fp:
                self = pickle.load(fp)

    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename,'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(self, fp)
```

When loading I know that I can do something like

```
tmp = pickle.load(fp)
    self.a = tmp.a
    self.b = tmb.b
    ...
```

But I hope that there is a better way

---

I assume this question has been asked before, but couldn't find it :/

Comment: Why would you pickle the whole object? Pickle only the storage data you need - you'll have the structure already loaded so it makes little sense to try to save it with the data.

Comment: Agreed. I just don't know how to store all the data in a succinct way. I would prefer not having to write something for data object. How would I go about this?

Comment: You can pickle only relevant data with `__setstate__` and load it back with `__getstate__` magic methods. It not only gives you more control on how to save and bring back instance-relevant data but it also makes the pickling less error prone (accidental class overwrites and such). See the third example from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `self` within `__init__` is meaningless, since you're not modifying the object that `self` points to -- you're just binding the variable name `self` in the function to a different object.

What you can do instead is use a `staticmethod` or `classmethod` to perform the optional loading from cache:

```
class Data(object):
    @classmethod
    def init_cached(cls, filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):  # create new
            result = cls(filename)
            result.save(filename)
            return result
        else:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
                return pickle.load(fp)

    def __init__(self, filename):
        pass  # [... expensive computations]
```

Now, use `Data.init_cached()` instead of `Data()` to initialize your object.

---

A more fancy approach would involve overriding `Data.__new__()` to achieve the same thing, but where initialization with `Data()` transparently checks if a cached version exists:

```
class Data(object):
    def __new__(cls, filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):  # create new
            return super(Data, cls).__new__(cls, filename, _save=True)
        else:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
                return pickle.load(fp)

    def __init__(self, filename, _save=False):
        # [... expensive computations]
        if _save:
            self.save(filename)
```

Further reading: [Python's use of `__new__` and `__init__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)