# PyTorch specific inspection issues in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, pytorch

Has anyone been able to resolve PyTorch specific inspection issues in PyCharm? Previous posts for non-PyTorch related issues suggest upgrading PyCharm, but I'm currently at the latest version. One option is to of course disable certain inspections entirely, but I'd rather avoid that.

Example: `torch.LongTensor(x)` gives me "Unexpected argument...", whereas both call signatures (with and without `x`) are both supported.

Comment: There is now a [GitHub issue tracking this problem](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7318).

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's because `torch.LongTensor` has no `__init__` method for pycharm to find.

According to [this source](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html) that I found thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new#674369) :

> Use **__new__** when you need to control the creation of a new instance.
>   Use **__init__** when you need to control initialization of a new instance.
>
> **__new__** is the first step of instance creation.  It's called first,
>   and is responsible for returning a new instance of your class.  In
>   contrast, **__init__** doesn't return anything; it's only responsible for
>   initializing the instance after it's been created.
>
> In general, you shouldn't need to override **__new__** unless you're
>   subclassing an immutable type like str, int, unicode or tuple.

Since `Tensor`s are types, it makes sense to define only `new` and no `init`.

You can experiment this behavior by testing the following classes :

```
torch.LongTensor(1)  # Unexpected arguments
```

Produces the warning while the following doesn't.

```
class MyLongTensor(torch.LongTensor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

MyLongTensor(1)  # No error
```

To confirm that the absence of `__init__` is the culprit try :

```
class Example(object):
    pass

Example(0)  # Unexpected arguments
```

To find out by yourself, use pycharm to `Ctrl+click` on `LongTensor` then `_TensorBase` and look at the defined methods.