# Why should I use __new__ instead of __init__ in this example?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have been studying `__new__` recently, and I've read lots of code where  `__new__`  is used instead of `__init__`. Sometimes I think both work, but I don't know why the original author uses `__new__`.

Can someone explain why the below code uses `__new__` instead of `__init__`? I want a reason for this example. I know the difference between `__new__` and `__init__`, but I don't know why `__new__` is used here.

[Example](https://github.com/autotest/tp-qemu/blob/master/qemu/tests/cpuflags.py#L484):

```
    class MiniSubtest(object):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kargs):
            self = super(MiniSubtest, cls).__new__(cls)
            ret = None
            if args is None:
                args = []
            try:
                ret = self.test(*args, **kargs)
            finally:
                if hasattr(self, "clean"):
                    self.clean()
            return ret
```

and I think if I use __init__, it still works, whey it used __new__?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's use of \_\_new\_\_ and \_\_init\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

Comment: `__init__` and `__new__` are _not_ the same. `__new__` is the method that actually creates instances of a class. It returns a new class instance. Once `__new__` has created the instance, it is passed into `__init__` via the first argument commonly named `self`. `__init__` is the method that allows you to customize the instance by initializing attributes.

Comment: Yuck. Don't use a class here; use a factory function

Comment: I know that, but can you explain to me why this specific case use __new__, I think we can use __init__ too.

Comment: @ChamK. Yes, this is a possible duplicate. But that original post is from '09, meaning it is implying Python 2, and this question is from 2017, implying that it is Python 3.  There are so many differences between the two that even in cases that haven't changed, like [`__new__`](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html#using-init-vs-new-in-metaclasses), can we allow Python 3 & Python 2 questions to diverge in SO?  Thanks!

Comment: To add on to @ppperry, here is a [tutorial of a factory function](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html).

Comment: Side note: `if args is None: ...` is redundant here, because `*args` always creates a `tuple`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Answer (score 2):

This controls the creation and return of the new instance:

- First the instance is created.
- The try clause catching an exception during testing the new instance.
- Then if there is exception, it cleans the instance's garbage.
- Then it returns None rather than the instance.

So it decides to return an instance or to discard it.

Answer (score 0):

`__new__` is used to control the creation of a new instance and expects you to return it whereas `__init__` only let you initialize an instance that has already been created

My guess is that `self.test` returns a different type of instance depending on the parameters

Comment: Hi, why it need to return a different type of instance when using __new__, and, I don't see it return a different type of instances if you go to https://github.com/autotest/tp-qemu/blob/master/qemu/tests/cpuflags.py#L484

Comment: since I think _\_init__ can be used here, I'll close this question if someone explained to me why it used _\_new__, and I don't think it's a duplicated question, I gave a specific example here, I hope the answer would be specific too.