# Is it reasonable to let __init__ member must take self parameter?

Tags: python

I find when `__init__` method lacks `self` parameter, only if there is no instantiation of this class, the compiler won't complain:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
class A():
    def __init__():
        print("A()")
$ ./test.py
```

But if there is a instantiation, the running time error will occur:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
class A():
    def __init__():
        print("A()")

A()
$ ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    A()
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Per my understanding, `__init__()` seems no use because it can't make any instance. So why doesn't the Python compiler enforce limitation such as when no `self` parameter in `__init__` function, it will show error message? Is it reasonable? Or I miss something.

Comment: You should modify the declaration of init from `def __init__():` to: `def __init__(self):` any class method should have `self` passed in as the first argument.

Comment: The thing is, it's not an error when you don't include the self argument. The `__init__` just doesn't take an argument. BUT when you create an instance, Python implicitly calls the initializer WITH A PARAMETER, the instance. Thus the error.

Comment: Why add more special cases? The closer `__init__` is to every other method, the better. Python will let you write `{**5}` and other things that don’t usually make sense, too, as long as you don’t run them.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is not a special name at *compilation* time.

It is possible to do things with the symbol `A.__init__` other than invoke it by trying to construct an `A`, and I think it is possible to replace the unusable `__init__` function with a different function at runtime prior to trying to construct an `A`.

The check for a correct number of arguments is made when `__init__` is called, as it is for any other method.

Answer (score 0):

it must be one argument at least, we call it "self" usually, so your Python code maybe have a small change

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A()")

A()
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is the initialization of an already created instance of a class, therefore it needs self, just like every other class method.  If you want to handle the creation of the class, that is the `__new__` method.  [This seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/169296) a good description.

Don't let the fact that python doesn't complain unless the method is called confuse you.