# correctly override __new__ in python3

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-3.5, factory-pattern

So I am trying to override `__new__` and let it exist as a factory to create
derived instances. After some reading on SO, I am under the impression that I should be calling `__new__` on the derived instance as well.

**BaseThing**

```
class BaseThing:
    def __init(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

    # methods to be derived
```

**ThingFactory**

```
class Thing(BaseThing):
    def __new__(cls, name, **kwargs):
        if name == 'A':
           return A.__new__(name, **kwargs)
        if name == 'B':
           return B.__new__(name, **kwargs)        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)

   # methods to be implemented by concrete class (same as those in base)
```

**A**

```
class A(BaseThing):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

**B**

```
class B(BaseThing):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

what I am expecting was that it'd just work.

```
>>> a = Thing('A')
```

gives me `TypeError: object.__new__(X): X is not a type object (str)`

I am bit confused by this; when I just return a concrete instance of derived classes, it just worked. i.e.

```
def __new__(cls, name, **kwargs):
        if name == 'A':
           return A(name)
        if name == 'B':
           return B(name)
```

I don't think this is the correct way to `return` in `__new__`; it may duplicate the calls to `__init__`.

when I am checking signatures of `__new__` in `object` it seems be this one:

```
@staticmethod # known case of __new__
def __new__(cls, *more): # known special case of object.__new__
    """ Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature. """
    pass
```

I didn't expect this was the one; I'd expect it came with args and kwargs as well. I must have done something wrong here.

it seems to me that I need to inherit object directly in my base but could  anyone explain the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You seem to have assigned something to `X`.

Comment: @user2357112 updated the question.

Comment: Your thing factory doesn't need to be a subclass of `Thing`; a regular function like `def thing_factory(name, *args, **kwargs): if name == "A": return A(*args, **kwargs) ...` would suffice.

Comment: Where  'A' is coming from: `return A.__new__(name, **kwargs)` ? As error explains, 'A' is not an object.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually tried to run any code version you posted. This code wouldn't have produced the error you claim, and it even contains obvious syntactical errors like `return return A(name)`. Posting code that doesn't reproduce your error tends to attract downvotes.

Comment: @ElisByberi ok yes, I guess that's a further evidence proving I am calling __new__ wrong. thanks

Comment: @stucash Why do you need to call new? It is called whenever you create a new class object!

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for that, but I guess that'd be something once you pointed out I could easily rectify. and for not running this codes, I guess it's yes and no, I won't argue this. I'll take this blame. I do have live codes which is far more complex so I could only create same skeleton here.

Comment: @stucash Test your code before coming here. You are welcome! Come prepared next time! :-)

Comment: @ElisByberi it's half learning to be honest; making correct use of `__new__` we could implement the factory pattern in a different way for it looks a bit nicer..

Comment: @ElisByberi yep will defo do that, now at least I think the downvote is not wrong. thanks for helping out!

Comment: @stucash This will help you for next time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for letting me, I genuinely appreciated it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're calling `__new__` wrong. If you want your `__new__` to create an instance of a subclass, you don't call the subclass's `__new__`; you call the superclass's `__new__` as usual, but *pass it the subclass* as the first argument:

```
instance = super().__new__(A)
```

I can't guarantee that this will be enough to fix your problems, since the code you've posted wouldn't reproduce the error you claim; it has other problems that would have caused a different error first (infinite recursion). Particularly, if `A` and `B` don't really descend from `Thing`, that needs different handling.

Comment: thanks and I have actually fixed circula dependency by using this implementation, but with returning instances directly.  calling `__new__` wrong I guess might be my real problem; I am going to try it and update it later.. peculiar that you didn't get the same error.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I have corrected the codes now. if you run them you should be able to reproduce the error.