# Why does a base class singleton still call the constructor mulitple times?

Tags: python, singleton

I am defining a Python singleton as follows:

```
class Database:
    initialized = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = random.randint(1,101)
        print("Generated an id of ", self.id)
        print("Loading database from file")

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Database, cls)\
                .__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

This works in the sense that every single call to `Database()` actually returns one and only instance. However, the `__init__()` method is *still* called on every invocation. For example,

```
database = Database()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = Database()
    d2 = Database()

    print(d1.id, d2.id)
    print(d1 == d2)
    print(database == d1)
```

Produces the output

```
Generated an id of  8
Loading database from file
Generated an id of  89
Loading database from file
Generated an id of  81
Loading database from file
81 81
True
True
```

Why is that? What can I do to avoid the initializer being called more than once?

Comment: A workaround would be to set `cls.initialized` to `True` in `__new__()` and then check its value in the `__init__()` method (and don't do anything when it's `True`).

Comment: @martineau this does not work. if I cordon off everything with `if not self.initialized`, trying to access the database's `id` results in an error.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness -- similar question and underlying problem was addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new (not exactly a duplicating question though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an instance is a two steps routine: ① Create a "blank" instance by calling `cls.__new__()`, then ② initialize this blank instance by calling `obj.__init__()`.

In your case, creating a new instance of your class calls your `__new__()` which always returns the same (not so blank) instance which then gets initialized properly by calling `__init__()` in it (sorry for the pun).

I am not sure if there is a way to avoid calling the `__init__()`, at least no straight-forward one, I think.  I would accept this and just keep an empty `__init__()` which doesn't hurt when called.

Or, maybe it is generally a better idea not to create new instances of your singleton (which then happen to turn out to be the *same* instance due to your special `__new__()` method).  Instead just use `cls.singleton` to store your one and only instance (the singleton) or just use the class itself as the singleton and make everything in class and static methods.  I typically go for the latter option.