# object takes no parameters after defining __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

In python 3.3 and later, when we override `__new__()`, we don't have to pass arguments and keyword arguments to `super().__new__()` or `object.__new__()`. But this call to `super().__new__()` returns an instance of a class.

How does python pass the rest of the arguments to `__init__` then?

```
class Spam(object):
    ''' Hello I am Spam '''

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Instance")
        instance = object.__new__(cls) # Who passed *args and **kwargs to __init__?
        print(instance)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print("Init Called")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Can someone please explain whats happening here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is \_\_init\_\_() always called after \_\_new\_\_()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed *cls* as an argument to *object.__new__*, so the interpreter can check whether *instance* is an instance of *cls*.

The initializer (*__init__*) is  automatically called by the allocator (*__new__*) as [[Python.Docs]: object.__new__(cls[, ...])](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) states (**emphases** are mine):

> If [__new__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) returns an instance of *cls*, **then the new instance’s [__init__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`**, where *self* is the new instance and **the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to [__new__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)**.
>
> If [__new__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s [__init__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method will **not** be invoked.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


class Spam(object):
    ''' Hello I am Spam '''

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Instance")
        instance = object.__new__(cls) # Who passed *args and **kwargs to __init__?
        print(instance)
        #return instance  # If you return anything else (1, object(), or None by commenting the line) here, __init__ won't be called
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:  # DO NOT DO THIS!!! It's just for demo purposes
            return instance


    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print("Init Called")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


def main():
    spam = Spam(1, 2)
    print(type(spam), dir(spam))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} on {0:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054511671>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Creating Instance
> <__main__.Spam object at 0x000001F8E24D14E0>
> Init Called
> <class '__main__.Spam'> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b']
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054511671>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py arg
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Creating Instance
> <__main__.Spam object at 0x0000020808F71550>
> <class 'NoneType'> ['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
> ```

Note that this isn't specific  to *Python **3*** (check [[Python 2.Docs]: Data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model)), but rather to [[Python]: New-style Classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle)
For more details, you could also check check [[Python 2.2.Docs]: Overriding the __new__ method](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__) (the *Singleton* class).

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for the response. Though I am not sure what is the intent behind this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean? It's kind of obvious. The syntax is clearer (simpler for the user). Note that the same thing also works in *Python **2.7.15***.

Answer (score 1):

What matters here is the initial call, say `spam = Spam('x', 1)`.

Internally, Python calls `__new__` as a class method on class `Spam` **with the passed parameters**. What `Spam.__new__` actually does is not really important, it is just supposed to return an object.

It does use `object.__new__` to build a `Spam` object. As the created object has the correct class, Python calls `__init__` on it **with the initial parameters**.

Comment: Thanks Serge. The point mentioned by @ChristiFati is really worth understanding. I am not sure how that "return instance" statement is making a difference. Even if it makes a difference what could have been an intent behind that.