# How to not create an object when there is an exception (python)?

Tags: python, class, exception

I created a class, that accepts an argument, and when the type of this argument is not string, it raises an exception. Well, it raises the exception when I want to create an object of this class and the argument is not string, but it creates the object anyway. Is there any way to prevent object from creation?

```py
class Movie():
    def __init__(self, name):
        if type(name) != str:
            raise Exception("name should be string")
        else:
            self.name = name
```

`movie = Movie(1)`

Here I get the exception but if I `print(movie)`, I get the location of the object in the memory. I want to get an error, that this name is not defined. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: probably you would want to override the __new__ method since that controls the creation of an object - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new)

Comment: Maybe with "del self" before raise

Comment: [Cannot reproduce?](https://tio.run/##VU7LDsIgELzzFWtPkBgvxotJjx79BoLtYjehQLrU2K9HQKNxbjuz84hbmoI/5jw4wwzX8CCU6iygYEQLWpOnpLVkdHYP3sz4USvIQtoiykbDrgdOy0@tWAwxwuU5YEwUvOzqK/AUVjfCDauB/L1TXxM6xv@I2nxotr71CzHXleV6rz0pEUtIko1WOb8A)

Comment: If I run your code then "movie" is not defined

Comment: @Wonka That worked. Thanks

Comment: @ForceBru I use jupyter notebook. I can still continue without getting an exit code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also it's better to use `isinstance(foo, str)` instead of `type(foo) == str`

Comment: @A.Heidary do you have something assigned to "movie" already in your terminal? What happens if you try the above in a fresh terminal?

Comment: @A.Heidary, that shouldn't be possible: run `a=int('hello');print(a)`, for example. You should get a `ValueError` while instantiating the `int` object and you shouldn't be able to access `a` if it wasn't previously defined.

Comment: @IainShelvington I did not. I got something like <__main__.Movie at 0x00000bc2423>. with `del self` before  `raise` now I get NameError

Comment: @ForceBru It's possible in my notebook. :) I've got this, that's why I post this question.

Comment: Normally a factory method would be used. Creating and then destroying the object is not a great solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution, del self object before raise

```
class Movie():
    def __init__(self, name):
        if type(name) != str:
            del self
            raise Exception("name should be string")
        else:
            self.name = name
```