# When is an object initialized in a Python constructor expression?

Tags: python

Let's say we call a constructor expression:

```
account2 = Account('John Paul', Decimal('-1234'))
```

The class definition has an initialization method of:

```
def __init__(self, name, balance):
    if balance < Decimal('0.00'):
        raise ValueError

    self.name = name
    self.balance = balance
```

In our constructor expression call the balance is negative and a `ValueError` is raised by the `__init__` method.

If I then try to reference the variable *account* I get a `NameError` from my REPL.  However, doesn't the class object have to be instantiated for that reference 'self' to be passed into `__init__` for the initialization method to run in the first place?

I think that Python is reacting correctly, but I'm a tad confused how Python works in the background.

[image]

Comment: please, provide error traceback and steps to reproduce an error

Comment: The right hand side is always completely evaluated before being assigned to your variable. As `Account('John Green', Decimal('-60.00'))` couldn't be evaluated, nothing got assigned to `account`.

Comment: "If I then try to reference the variable account..." Please show code that illustrates this verbal description.

Comment: The *object* certainly existed, in order for `.__init__()` to be invoked on it.  However, the exception was raised before that object could be stored anywhere; the assignment to `account2` never took place.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: @user3558409 the object is constructed before it is passed to `__init__`.  The object is created by `__new__`, then the result of that is passed to `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks all.  Question answered in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers address why you get an error when trying to refer to `account` later - it's because the "assignment" part of the statement doesn't execute after the "construct" part of the statement runs into its own error.

I'll answer the other half of your question:

> However, doesn't the class object have to be instantiated for that reference 'self' to be passed into `__init__` for the initialization method to run in the first place?

If you've ever wondered why `__init__()` is called "init", instead of something else, this is why.

The process that happens when you invoke a class like that (`Account(...)`) actually has two phases. `__init__()` is the second phase - initialization, wherein an already-allocated object is customized and prepared. The first phase is a method called `__new__()`.

`__new__()` is a static method, and it's responsible for creating the object to which `self`, in `__init__()`, refers.

Python documents `__new__()` in [the data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new) for more detail in the order of execution.

Answer (score 4):

- *An* object is created implicitly with `__new__`.
- That object is passed as `self` to `__init__`.
- `__init__` raises an exception.
- The exception cause the expression `Account(...)` to, well, raise an exception, which causes the statement `account = ...` to not complete.

So yes, the object did exist briefly while the right hand side of the assignment statement was being evaluated, but it never got to the stage where that object would have been assigned to `account`.

Answer (score 2):

> However, doesn't the class object have to be instantiated for that reference 'self' to be passed into `__init__` for the initialization method to run in the first place?

Yes, `self` has a valid value inside `__init__()`. However, `account` is not assigned a value until after `__init__()` returns successfully. Since an error is thrown instead, `account` never gets assigned a value.

> is the object still instantiated, but floating around in space without the attributes filled in. `__init__` is still called with self after all.

Yes, the object is still in memory somewhere. But since there are no references to it, it is elligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Just a note, in CPython, objects with a reference count of 0 are reclaimed *immediately*, but the language does not guarantee that, simply that they are eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `Account('John Paul', Decimal('-1234'))` then first [`Account.__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is called to create the object and if that object is an instance of `Account` then [`Account.__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is invoked to further customize that object. Both actions are performed as a result of `Account(...)` and are used to compute the r.h.s. of the assignment:

```
account2 = Account('John Paul', Decimal('-1234'))
```

If an error is raised during that computation no value exists to be assigned and so the assignment never happens. That's why you receive the `NameError`.

You can use the following example class to verify that both `__new__` and `__init__` are called:

```
class Account:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__new__({cls}, {args}, {kwargs})')
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__init__({self}, {args}, {kwargs})')
        raise ValueError()


Account('John Paul', -1234)
```

which prints:

```
__new__(<class '__main__.Account'>, ('John Paul', -1234), {})
__init__(<__main__.Account object at 0x7fafcdfacd68>, ('John Paul', -1234), {})
```

Comment: `__new__` is special-cased to be a static method; you don't need the decorator.