# What is the difference between "Creating an object" and "Initializing" an object?

Tags: python

Recently, I saw someone talking about a `__new__` method and read an article about it. ( I always used `__init__` before and never knew about `__new__`) The article explained that the `__new__` method was called when an object is created and the `__init__` method will be called to initialize the object.

What is the difference? What does it mean to initialize the object?

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are being called. `__new__` is called first and it return an instance of the class. This instance is passed to `__init__` as `self`.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In python EVERYTHING is an object so when you create a class, python create a class object. Assume this code:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.var = 0
```

python create a Example class object. In this object there are some methods such as `__init__` and `__new__`. Then assume this peace of code:

```
obj = Example()
```

in runtime python is calling the `__new__` method on Example class object and pass the istance (the `__new__` result) to the `__init__` method. And now you have your object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in link below and in my experience, we always use `__init__` to define class constructor, but I rarely have seen that anyone uses `__new__` .

Another point that is explained is that use `__new__` if you're subclassing an immutable type like str, int, Unicode, or tuple. Immutable objects are Objects that wont change during program running.

https://dev.to/pila/constructors-in-python-init-vs-new-2f9j