# Why is return included in the alternative constructor?

Tags: python, oop, constructor, class-method

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    @classmethod    
    def from_string(cls, emp_str):
        first, last = emp_str.split("-")
        return cls(first, last)

Student_1 = Student("Cool", "Person")

Student_2 = "Another-One"

Student_2 = Student.from_string(Student_2)
```

Why is return used in this class method? I know you need it to work. But I'm not able to wrap my mind around why you need to include it. From what I know - in this example in the classmethod, `cls(first, last)` is doing the same thing as `__init__(self, first, last)`. But why the need to include a `return` in there? Shouldn't just `cls(first, last)` be enough to call the `__init__`, which is what you already do when constructing the instance like `Student_1`?

Can you explain where my confusion lies?

Comment: Note that `__init__` is *not* a constructor. It is an initialiser for an already constructed object.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't just `cls(first, last)` be enough to call the `__init__`, which is what you already do when constructing the instance like `Student_1`?

Yes, calling the constructor like this will result in `__init__` being called on a new instance of `cls`. However, without `return`, that new instance will be **discarded** and nothing will be returned from the `from_string()` method.

It might be more clear if you make it a global function rather than a class method. Can you see the difference between these two functions and why the first one doesn't work?

```
class Student:
    ...


def student_from_string(emp_str):
    first, last = emp_str.split("-")
    Student(first, last)

student_from_string("A-B")  # None


def student_from_string(emp_str):
    first, last = emp_str.split("-")
    return Student(first, last)

student_from_string("A-B")  # Student("A", "B")
```

Why **isn't** `return` needed in `__init__`? Because you're not calling `student = [new student].__init__(...)`, you're using `student = Student(...)`. `__init__` is a special initialization method that is not expected to return anything. You rarely call it explicitly (except on `super()`), but it is called automatically during a normal constructor call.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/23649

Answer (score 0):

You notice that `from_string` is a classmethod (not instance method).
In the line `Student_2 = Student.from_string(Student_2)`

When you call **from_string**, it is assigned to another variable. (you are assigning to the same Student_2 )

Without return, this assignment will not happen (None will return there.)

[Note that, cls function returns an object instance]

The `__instance__` and `from_string` are not doing the same thing here.
Inside **instance**, you are assigning the values to instance properties.
But from_string, you are calling the constructor again, to assign the parameters in the instance properties.