# correct way of extending a class in python

Tags: python, initialization, mixins

I am given a designated factory of `A`-type objects. I would like to make a new version of `A`-type objects that also have the methods in a `Mixin` class. For reasons that are too long to explain here, I can't use `class A(Mixin)`, I have to use the `A_factory`. Below I try to give a bare bones example.

I thought naively that it would be sufficient to inherit from `Mixin` to endow `A`-type objects with the mixin methods, but the attempts below don't work:

```py
class A: pass

class A_factory:
    def __new__(self):
        return A()
        
class Mixin:
    def method(self):
        print('aha!')

class A_v2(Mixin):  # attempt 1
    def __new__(cls):
        return A_factory()

class A_v3(Mixin):  # attempt 2
    def __new__(cls):
        self = A_factory()
        super().__init__(self)
        return self
```

In fact `A_v2().method()` and `A_v3().method()` raises `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'method'`.

What is the correct way of using `A_factory` within `class A_vn(Mixin)` so that `A`-type objects created by the factory inherit the mixin methods?

Comment: Why not `class A(Mixin)`? Why do you need `A_factory`?

Comment: I need to use `A_factory` because it contains a lot of logic for creating and initializing the appropriate `A` (`A`-type objects don't have a simple initialization). I just need to add some functionality to those objects.

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious reason why you should need `__new__` for what you're showing here.  There's a nice discussion here on the subject: [Why is __init__() always called after __new__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new)

If you try the below it should work:

```py
class Mixin:
    def method(self):
        print('aha!')

class A(Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

test = A()
test.method()
```

If you need to use a factory method, it should be a function rather than a class.  There's a very good discussion of how to use factory methods here: https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am asking. What I am asking is: if I have to use a given factory of objects, how do I extend their functionality?

Comment: @Ziofil Can you edit your question to better explain the problem?