Why defining empty __new__(cls) method in python class prevent __init__ from running
In next super-primitive code when __new__ method is defined __init__ method for created objects is not called.
class NaiveSingleton:

    def __new__(cls):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        print("NaiveSingleton init called")

so, call
    nsA1 = NaiveSingletonA()
    nsA2 = NaiveSingletonA()

brings no __init__ printout. Why?
Second question:
Why definition of empty __new__ method make this class work as singleton?

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.new If new() does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s init() method will not be invoked.

nsA1 and nsA2 are None, so I'm not sure what you mean by make this class work as singleton.

All that an empty __new__ does is to always return None, which is a singleton itself. But that doesn't make the class work as a singleton in the common sense of the word since the class does not instantiate any instance of the class.

The default behaviour of __new__ method is to call the parent class's __new__ (which is object.__new__ for built-in classes). In this case, object.__new__ creates a new instance of the class. And  since your __new__ is empty, it doesn't return anything (None) and the __init__ constructor won't be called. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new?rq=2 since it is related to this post.

As @Guy correctly noted in aforomented example both nsA1 and nsA2 are None, because __new__ method does not contain return statement.
